# Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here

Tags: support, attribution, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

**NB** The following is a community-generated list of websites that republish Stack Exchange content without attributing it properly. It is no longer being maintained, because the procedure for reporting such sites has changed; see the duplicate for more information.

There are a number of license-violating clones of Stack Exchange sites popping up that use Stack Exchange's [CC-wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license) data without following our Creative Commons attribution terms. Those terms are [linked at the bottom of every Stack Exchange webpage](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), and are also included as a `.txt` file in every data dump we produce.

---

Google now has [a form for reporting content copiers **that appear above the originals**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dGM4TXhIOFd3c1hZR2NHUDN1NmllU0E6MQ&ndplr=1) in search results.

Also, you can [block unwanted sites from appearing in Google search from the search page itself](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1224171&answer=1210386&rd=1):

> The option to block a site appears when you click a search result and then navigate back to the search results page. Click the "Block" link next to that result to block all pages within the site's entire domain.

---

This post was created as an attempt to organize information originally posted [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106824/131713). You may also be looking for [the post for reporting copycat sites that outrank Stack Exchange in search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71820/131713).

Comment: I have never seen the CAPTCHA page as often as I did when I was adding the existing 40 or so answers to this question.

Comment: That is because you pasted. Try typing... Like a real person :)

Comment: ...yeeeeahhhh, I prefer the CAPTCHAs.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I would put a *poison pill* question(s) that only those APIs presented so that you could automatically re-scrap via Google and easily find infringing sites. Much like cartographers do on physical maps by putting fake locations or markers to easily spot copies. The thieves would never know what to look for and you could easily make this an automated process.

Comment: @Jeff is this handled at some level? Can we know which sites were reported and closed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I don't have a handy list of sites that have been dealt with, but we do monitor this thread and contact offenders. This post isn't just a black hole. :)

Comment: It's a bit late for this comment, but if you ever want to check out what one of these sites looked like (if it was later removed), you can use one of the many webcache services online (I use the chrome web cache plugin)

Comment: Site blocking is currently unavailable through google unless you use Chrome and the Chrome blocking extension.  http://searchengineland.com/google-block-sites-feature-146409

Comment: I just went through and about 50% of these are gone. I edited some, until I got tired of it. Cleanup please? :)

Comment: @PopularDemand: Can you check nerdanswer.com please? I'm not entirely sure whether to classify it as an illegal clone or not.

Comment: @Karan FYI I'm just the user who posted the question, not an official person of any kind.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Thanks, maybe a mod will check it out then if they ever read my previous comment.

Comment: Is there a reason [the original list of offenders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/106824) was split into countless posts over multiple pages? Giving it its own topic, sure, but splitting into individual answers just makes searching for existing entries a PITA and invites duplicates.

Comment: Here's another one I don't think has been reported earlier, with fake author names and as far as I can see no attribution whatsoever: eonlinegratis.com/channel/superuser/

Comment: http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=58732. here's one more that has a copy of this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182540/how-can-i-parse-different-json-urls-when-clicking-on-an-item-in-a-listview

Comment: The following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116819/jinja-url-named-routes-escaped-curly-brace-literal

Can be found on the following sites without attribution or mention of SO:

- ````http://www.dvlup.com/Community/View/12116819?sort=newest&tag=braces````
- ````http://t590.codeinpro.us/q/51501703e8432c0426055493````
- ````http://www.happyforlove.com/questions/a_12116819/jinja-url-named-routes-escaped-curly-brace-literal````
- ````http://www.solutionoferror.com/python/jinja-url-named-routes-escaped-curly-brace-literal-40785.asp````

Comment: The following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962307/how-to-merge-two-rendertargetbitmap-instances

Appears here without attribution: ````http://www.kacode.com/v101139-.html````

Comment: Are the copy websites obliged to update their pages if they change on SO/SE?

Comment: @Herbert no, they're not. The version of the content they have is still licensed CC BY-SA.

Comment: Does that also hold for names coupled to comments, questions and answers?

Comment: @Herbert I would _imagine_ so... but I'll have to defer to an SE employee for the official answer.

Comment: happyforlove.com seems to be ripping off SU, SO and perhaps other SE sites as well.

Comment: www.codeinpro.us, no attribution.

Comment: @AnnaLear The RNQA site seems to still be going strong; [here’s an ELU meta post about them scraping content from ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/www-rqna-net-scraping-elu-and-se-content). If there is anything more we can do, please let us know and we would be glad to pitch in in any way we can. Thanks.

Comment: @Pops maybe better lock that question and add a more outstanding notice? Users keep adding sites by editing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I will become rich and famous after I figure out a solution to the "people don't read" problem. Until then, I'm taking your lock suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 51):

**rqna.net, rqgg.net**

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/sqqsw-determine-nsdate-for-memorial-day-in-a-given-year.html` =
[Determine NSDate for Memorial Day in a given year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147450/determine-nsdate-for-memorial-day-in-a-given-year) (SO)

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/nyhx-canon-g1-x-custom-color-resets.html` = [Canon G1 X Custom Color Resets](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24470/canon-g1-x-custom-color-resets) (photo.se)

*Update [March 22, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171631/131713):*
This post was copied from Stackoverflow.com. It mentions the SO author's user ID, but does not say that the content is copied, or provide any link to the original post.

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/vnzkq-converting-marshalling-a-vb-6-type-to-structure-in-vb-net.html`

As of June 9th, 2013, they appear to still be ripping content from the Stack Exchange network; this question is copied from Arqade with no attribution:

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/purwup-where-can-i-find-each-type-of-ultra-rare-cargo.html`

They're still copying content as of August 4, 2013. This was copied from Programmers, and they didn't bother to strip out the duplicate notice:

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/pyytxk-is-it-poor-programming-practice-to-pass-parameters-as-objects-duplicate.html`

The same people run rqgg.net, example: `http://www.rqgg.net/topic/pynmq-why-are-the-bridges-of-klingon-ships-so-steamy.html` (from [Why are the bridges of Klingon ships so steamy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36494/why-are-the-bridges-of-klingon-ships-so-steamy))

---

*Update Aug 9, 2013*

An [entire copy](http://www.rqna.net/index-qoh.html) of the [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (give or take a few days) is replicated on rqna.net.

It not only copies the question and answer, but seems to make fake 'user accounts' that aggregate the data taken.

Also,  `http: //www. rqgg.net/ topic/ nzxp-two-photons-transition.html` copied [this answer from Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/two-photons-transition/57235#57235). This was reported [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4709/plagiarism-from-other-sites) initially.

---

Copy http://gaming.stackexchange.com content and even "generously" state it's CC-BY-SA. But no link back.

e.g. `http://www.rqgg.net/topic/ikyxs-how-to-sort-the-special-offers-list-by-relative-discount.html` boldly copies [How to sort the special offers list by relative discount?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110491/how-to-sort-the-special-offers-list-by-relative-discount)

The username links `http://www.rqgg.net/list/Zommuter.html` to a list multiple other questions by me, but there doesn't seem to be any way of knowing it's from ArQAde.

---

This one is a bit different, `http://www.rqgg.net/topic/rphzq-starcraft-1-disc-2-isnt-continuing-the-installation.pdf`, it was posted as a pdf file instead of html. It is a complete copy of [Starcraft 1 disc 2 isn't continuing the installation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/126684/47872) .

As before, there is no recognition of this being StackExchange content and the usernames link to fake accounts.

Comment: This is the same as the zqna one.

Comment: http://www.rqna.net/qna/nrvutw-lxml-classic-get-text-content-except-for-that-of-nested-tags.html and [lxml classic: Get text content except for that of nested tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8141956) etc.

Comment: zqna is gone, but rqna is still going. For example: http://www.rqna.net/qna/yyqvy-best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code.html is a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489065/best-practice-to-call-configureawait-for-all-server-side-code

Comment: rqna is still going alright: `http://www.rqna.net/qna/kmkmyq-how-to-put-both-image-and-text-into-a-cell-for-jqgrid.html` is an exact copy of [**SO: how-to-put-both-image-and-text-into-a-cell-for-jqgrid**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526096/how-to-put-both-image-and-text-into-a-cell-for-jqgrid) without any contribution or link to the original SO question.

Comment: There is also `rqgg.net` which looks like the same site. Example: `rqgg.net/topic/mmiur-disabling-foreign-key-checks-on-the-command-line.html`

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386925/xcode-4-3-codesign-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected-is-va vs. `http://www.rqna.net/qna/muhwvz-xcode-4-3-codesign-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected-is-valid.html`

Comment: They are also hot-linking images from `i.stack.imgur.com`

Comment: Their address is only an hour; I could visit them.

Comment: They are still up, see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319221 vs. `http://www.rqna.net/qna/pqvkyp-prove-set-of-nash-equilibria-is-closed.html#pqvkyq`

Comment: What is the current status regarding the DMCA of this website?

Comment: @Herbert That’s a very good question. They’re still scraping ELU, as [reported on ELU’s meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4070/www-rqna-net-scraping-elu-and-se-content).

Comment: They're also taking content from Biology, e.g. `http://www.rqna.net/list/Oreotrephes.html`

Comment: We just got [a fresh report](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4709/520) from Physics.SE.

Comment: Its still coping from Movies.SE and not solved yet.

Comment: @DIMension10 please don't add here anymore, there is [new procedure to report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/152859).

Answer (score 29):

**hows.info** (also **serverfault.hows.info**)

- copies all user pages, questions, etc.
- no attribution
- adds ads (inline text links and block ads)
- uses trademarked images and cdn resources
- purports to be Stack Overflow (contact page) Ironically even offers SE as a login

Site is pretty egregious, direct copy, user profiles and everything. Only site with 100% user profile copies that I have found. Even uses the favicon.

At first the site wouldn't let me view (said I had reached my maximum or some message along those lines), and I had to delete the cookie on my machine from them in order to access the page. Once I realized it was a copy I stopped browsing because of the malicious nature of the owner.

Comment: We are keeping an eye on this one and beefing up the blocking on our end.

Comment: @AnnaLear What does "beefing up blocking" entail?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Blocking more proxies they're using, for one thing.

Comment: @user228379 Nope, shouldn't be protected. That's fixed now.

Comment: @AnnaLear There's now a Server Fault version `:o`

Comment: How come hows.info is sending me back to Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Louie Wow! It is! Maybe they blocked it and they just gave up and redirected back here, I have no idea :P the server fault one is still there though

Comment: @Anna Did you block them? Do you have any idea why they're redirecting back to SO?

Comment: @Doorknob No idea.

Comment: Okay, now it's giving be HTTP 522s. This is very odd.

Answer (score 26):

#### bigresource.com

- Example (`http://asp.net.bigresource.com/MVC-3-Razor-Syntax-partial-view-Menu-cshtml-with-full-markup-a9sAFbss8.html`) (Original on SO: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Syntax question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450596/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-syntax-question))
- No attribution
- No links
- They mangle the original text (e.g. leave out salutations)

Comment: That site is actually taken questions from all the popular websites and showing only the question and a link to jump to the main website for answer.

Comment: @AliAdravi I don't see that link.

Comment: Interesting that the website in your profile is `advancesharp.com`, another copycat site... why would you use both that and SO?

Comment: This one is actually starting to show _above_ SO in certain PHP related searches. Worth blocking `*.bigresource.com` as it keeps 'getting even bigger'.

Comment: I really despise that site

Answer (score 23):

#### www.advancesharp.com

Example:

[Why does $($) crash my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9585840/561731)

is the original; here is the copy:

`http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/7587/why-does-crash-my-page`

[Beating jQuery addiction: Which jQuery methods are easily translated into pure javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005211/beating-jquery-addiction-which-jquery-methods-are-easily-translated-into-pure-j) **original**

Copy: `http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/6463/beating-jquery-addiction-which-jquery-methods-are-easily-translated-into-pure-javascript` *which the owner of the site takes credit for... methinks Felix Kling will not be impressed.*

All content from this site appears to be ripped from SO.

This site appears to be owned and operated by [this SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586227/ali-adravi).

More examples:
ORIGINAL: ["javascript:void(0);" vs "return false" vs "preventDefault()"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3498492/750216)
COPY: `http://advancesharp.com/Questions/6474/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault`

There's [a post about this at the high-Google-ranking copiers question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here/136549#136549) as well.

### Edit:

It appears he is keeping tabs on us and removed this questions linked. Here is a quick example of how you can search his "most visited" questions (grab a chunk of code and/or text and google search)

[Using JQuery hover with HTML image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map)

`http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/64/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map`

The question has been changed slightly. The answer is exact. There are literally hundreds of scraped pieces of content on this site. Too much for it to be cross-post coincidence

### Edit:

I Just re-visited him and his 'newest' questions almost all seem legit? However there are still legacy scrapes on his site with names/times/people changed but not intellectual property.

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

and `http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/298/how-to-know-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-by-jquery`

and

[How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

`http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/221/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript`

or

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)
and

`http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/231/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object`

Really, after you find a bogus Question/Answer combo just click on the 'user' who posted it. All other content from said user is scraped from SO - and there are MANY of these users all with 2/3 questions / answers - I can't see it being an elaborate way for someone on that site to gain 'rep'

Comment: Erm... all of the URLs given 404 over at that site.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ it appears he removed those links - as mentioned he is an SO user and may have become privy to the fact we are on to him. I'm sure if you did a little research you could find some more. Did not take me long to find duplicates by searching popular questions on his site on google.

Comment: [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript) and [his question](http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/628/checking-if-an-associative-array-key-exists-in-javascript) also I have updated my post - need I be more thorough?

Comment: I think both I and the community see that the site owner is trying to avoid detection, but is doing so futilely.

Comment: [???](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187791/ali-adravi)

Comment: Yes... It appears so.

Comment: I marked this as resolved because I can't find any more SO questions on the site. It seems they've now resorted to just making a large number of fake users (all with fireworks for profile pics) and posting questions and answers about SO-like topics. Regardless, it seems to be original content, so it's no longer our concern.

Comment: [Nope.](http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/221/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) It seems the site went 'underground' until it got down to [0 stars](http://gta.neoseeker.com/wiki/Wanted_Level_System) but I visited some links now and they're all up. Interestingly, the answer in the question I re-linked has the following code in it: `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` Lol. Maybe the admin should put up a filter to block that kind of stuff?

Answer (score 22):

<s>**http://tinyguru.com/**</s>

`tinyguru.com/serverfault/qid428975.html` copies my Server Fault question [How to use tscon on Windows7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/428975/how-to-use-tscon-on-windows7)

EDIT:
tinyguru.com's 'questions about English' branch appears to have scraped english.SE wholesale. In other 'questions about X' branches, the Xs all represent X.SE.

Update (Aug 13 2013): Site now links directly to stackoverflow.com and attribution to the site and CC-BY-SA is stated in the page footer. Case closed?

Comment: Also `http://www.tinyguru.com/gis/qid29575.html` which duplicates http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/connect-to-postgresql-arcsde-10-1

Comment: They seem to duplicate almost every Stackexchange site (see `http://www.tinyguru.com`).

Comment: its changed I think..he he he.

Comment: Douglas isn't it legal to use data when it comply with all required attributes ?

Comment: I find it funny they have `superuser` in the URL

Comment: It seems this page is now only linking to SO questions and profiles. Nothing wrong with that I think?

Answer (score 17):

#### tips4all.net

- Example: `http://tips4all.net/make-xcode-4-stop-auto-staging-with-git.html` duplicates [Make Xcode 4 stop auto staging with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076911/make-xcode-4-stop-auto-staging-with-git)
- Author names have been changed and maybe randomized (the question "author" on tips4all does not have the same list of "Questions Asked" as the author on SO).
- No mention of, nor links to, SO that I can find.

Comment: Just came across this looking for something else.

Answer (score 15):

**solutionoferror.com**

They show you a question, and to get the answer, you need to view an offer.  You don't need to click on it, there is a "skip" button, but they are hiding other sites behind *their* offers, so they get money for sending you away from their site.

Working from my previous answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120770/152620), I googled:

```
TypeError: unbound method can_move() must be called with O_shape
```

The first result was Stack Overflow ([Python: Display Shape from Tetris Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995690/python-display-shape-from-tetris-game)), but the second was to that site:

```
http://www.solutionoferror.com/python/python-display-shape-from-tetris-game-77409.asp
```

Clicking "get complete solution" will bring you to an offer, clicking "skip offer" will then bring you to Stack Overflow.

P.S. I noticed that the questions on that site don't all go to Stack Overflow, they go to lots of different Q&A and forum sites :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14105686/785745 was 'translated' to `http://www.solutionoferror.com/asp-net/cuda-specific-error-s-111041.asp`

Comment: @KendallFrey: What the ...?  It looks like someone (badly) re-wrote the question and posted it there.  Weird.

Comment: solutionoferror.com seems to automatically paraphrase questions, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886430/passing-options-to-chrome-driver-selenium with `http://www.solutionoferror.com/java/passing-options-to-chrome-driver-selenium-123869.asp`.

Comment: @RobW: They went through the trouble of making look like it's not stolen >.<

Comment: Them: `http://www.solutionoferror.com/html/sublime-text-2-autocompleting-html-escaped-characters-starting-with-amper-40267.asp`
SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870427/sublime-text-2-autocompleting-html-escaped-characters-starting-with-ampersand

The site rates high on my malware-o-meter. It asked for a FB login (when you click whitespace) and to install Flash (when you go back).

Comment: Another one: `http://www.solutionoferror.com/asp-net/portable-class-library-and-net-concurrentdictionary-123158.asp` and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202150/portable-class-library-and-net-concurrentdictionary .

Comment: Still going : `http://www.solutionoferror.com/java/change-font-size-at-runtime-with-slider-for-entire-java-swing-application-w-261910.asp` vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004658/change-font-size-at-runtime-with-slider-for-entire-java-swing-application-with-n

Answer (score 14):

***.softuses.com**

Robotranslated content from SO used without any attribution.

Example:
`http://de.softuses.com/80577` is a copy of [removing/adding CALayers for GPU optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626316/removing-adding-calayers-for-gpu-optimization)

*Updated [May 15, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180309/131713):*
There are at least three subdomains copying here: **http://de.softuses.com/**, **http://fr.softuses.com/** and **http://es.softuses.com/**

Comment: Confirmed for fr.softuses.com just found a french post where they auto translate exactly the content of a SO question.

Comment: I find another subdomain http://ja.softuses.com/, it consists of many copies of SO content with robotoranslated to Japanese.

Answer (score 14):

**techques.com**

- The scraper also purports to give a link "View original page at" (no further text), but this link goes nowhere.  The scraper is presumably availing him/herself of a great deal of Stack Exchange content, a clearinghouse for SE content
- This scraper site is heavily ad supported
- Does state at the bottom that the content is licensed under cc-wiki and enumerates some (not all) SE sites involved, but does not link to the original question or the users.

A search for the term "Judaism" on their main site turns up over 600 hits on the subject, many, many of which (in a cursory search) are directly copied from Mi.Yodeya; a search for an active username turns up hundreds of hits, including questions, answers, and comments.

In addition, a search for "English Language & Usage" without the quotes turns up hundreds of hits (many from that SE site); searches for it with the quotes turns up 48; and searches for names with which I am familiar from other SE sites turn up content of those SE users.

The attribution is not only flimsy but actually incorrect. There's a disclaimer at the bottom of the main page (but over at Mi.Yodeya we believe it to be violating the license terms)

> The content is from serverfault.com, superuser.com and stackoverflow.com, 
>   and is licensed under cc-wiki. Any advice please contact us.

- Verbatim copies of [Mi.Yodeya (aka Judaism.SE)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)'s questions, answers, *and comments*, all without attribution.

#### Examples:

- `http://www.techques.com/question/31-20149/Which-font-is-the-most-comfortable-for-on-screen-viewing` from [Which font is the most comfortable for on-screen viewing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20149/which-font-is-the-most-comfortable-for-on-screen-viewing)
- `www.techques.com/question/27-1437/Cleaning-Tzitzis` is a copy of [Cleaning Tzitzis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1437/5).

Comment: Confirmed, and I also see this site scraping content from [physics.SE], e.g. [this](http://www.techques.com/question/5-5982/Current-Physical-Applications-of-Elastic-Fractals) ([original](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5982)). Who knows how many other network sites they are taking from (without any attribution whatsoever).

Comment: Funny: the copies faithfully reproduce inter-post links back to the originating Stack Exchange site (see for instance my answer on `http://www.techques.com/question/5-31514/Why-is-the-%28free%29-neutron-lifetime-so-long`? which links back to http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/31526/520). The person who wrote the scraper is too much of a poser to even get that right. *::sigh::* You just can't get good villians these days.

Comment: They've got stuff from AskUbuntu as well.

Comment: Here's an example from [meta.English Language & Usage](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4153/9001) showing three of the four attribution requirements aren't met. It looks like they're trying to meet them, but it's broken for non-SO content.

Comment: I reported content scraped from [Theoretical CS](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) as Google ranked it above the original.

Comment: Heh, I didn't realize there were ads, but I guessed there might be... AdBlock Plus is my friend!

Answer (score 13):

**www.dektak.com**

- Example (`http://www.www.dektak.com/questions/10009985/server-sent-events-vs-ajax-polling-vs-websockets-for-notifications`)(Copy of SO question [Server-Sent Events vs AJAX Polling vs WebSockets for Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009985/server-sent-events-vs-ajax-polling-vs-websockets-for-notifications))
- Questions do not have attribution
- Site calls itself Stack Exchange Network

Comment: Still in business as of October 2012: `http://www.www.dektak.com/questions/5479989/how-to-deep-copy-object-in-java`

Comment: Also is **hotlinking images from sstatic.net**.

Comment: Also seems to operate under the domain `117766.cn`.

Comment: Whois information: han meimei, qinghuayuanlu1198hao 34-343, nanjing, jiangsu 210007, CN; Phone: +1.02557716023; Email: tv025cn@sina.com

Comment: I have banned the network these guys appear to be scraping from, we'll see if there is any new content appearing next week.

Answer (score 13):

**happyforlove.com**

copies the content of SE sites without any attribution. For example, `http://www.happyforlove.com/questions/c_444314/prove-that-in-an-obtuse-triangle-the-orthocentre-is-the-excenter-of-the-orthic-t` is a copy of [this one on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444314/prove-that-in-an-obtuse-triangle-the-orthocentre-is-the-excenter-of-the-orthic-t).

The site has the footer:

> Copyright © 2013 www.happyforlove.com - All rights reserved.

(Site first noticed [by another user on Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10285/85506))

Comment: It's also pulling content from SF, and as far as I can see many other SE sites.

Answer (score 12):

**qandasys.info**

- No mentioning that this material is from SE
- No hyperlink to original question
- No hyperlinks to user names
- No attribution to authors or Stack Exchange
- No links back to Stack Exchange
- No mentioning that the content is licensed under CC BY-SA

After some brief investigation, it appears to pull from other Stack Exchange sites as well.

#### Examples

- Located an exact duplicate(`http://qandasys.info/has-anyone-gotten-sd-gundam-capsule-fighter-to-run-on-linux/`) of [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115872/47872) I asked with no attribution of any kind what so ever.
- `http://qandasys.info/gnuplot-ubuntu-12-10-kile-texlive2012-closed/`, Original [gnuplot, ubuntu 12.10, kile, texlive2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103168/gnuplot-ubuntu-12-10-kile-texlive2012)
- `http://qandasys.info/will-redd-always-have-at-least-one-real-piece-of-art-duplicate/` - Original Arqade Question: [Will Redd always have at least one real piece of art?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121292/will-redd-always-have-at-least-one-real-piece-of-art)

Comment: There's a lot of scraping from Arqade happening on this one.

Comment: Scratch that, they're scraping from multiple sites now.  I see at least a few questions from Photo.SE, and Sharepoint.SE.

Comment: One of their latest scrapes is completely blatant: `http://qandasys.info/how-to-do-organize-papers-urls-and-other-tcs-related-resources/` No attempt at all to reroute URLs.

Answer (score 12):

**`http://www.codeinpro.us/`**

- Example 1 from SO: (`http://t6865.codeinpro.us/q/51502614e8432c04262938ad`)
- Example 2 from SF: (`http://www.codeinpro.us/q/5080d39b4f1eba38a4995017`)
- Full text of question, all answers (including marking accepted answer), and all comments
- No attribution, no links, and no mention of SO, SF, or SE
- Only reviewed a few questions but everything I looked at is from a SE site.

Comment: Further example: `http://t8500.codeinpro.us/q/508109444f1eba38a4ed93c1 ` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063129/get-computer-name-on-mac

Comment: Another example: `http://t7890.codeinpro.us/q/5080e87c4f1eba38a4bc5945`

Comment: This site is still active at: `http://t7536.codeinpro.us/`

Comment: Another example: `http://t5766.codeinpro.us/q/51502642e8432c042629aff9` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-diagrams-like-this

Answer (score 11):

**[www.iasptk.com](http://www.iasptk.com)**

Example: `http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntuwp/tag/11-04/` contains content from many questions and answers.
At the time of this writing, the first question on that page is the AU question [Iptables proxy host on port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278486/iptables-proxy-host-on-port).

It goes as far as using the list of site tags and site name as headings/links, but does not indicate Stack Exchange as the source of the content.  The four requirements from [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) are not followed.

It also inappropriately uses the Ubuntu logo.

Comment: Inappropriate use of the Ubuntu logo should be reported to Canonical as the trademark owner.  See http://askubuntu.com/q/25072/44179

Answer (score 10):

**qnundrum.com**

`http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=19297` is a copy of a question from AskDifferent. It links to AskDifferent's author page and then gives no answer, just a button "View Full Answer on Apple StackExchange."

No attribution to us.

Note that its Contact page says

> If a question of yours was indexed by Qnundrum that you don't want indexed, click here to fill out a take down request form. Submitted questions for takedown that are approved will be removed within 48 hours.

And another `http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=597718`

and on 18 Aug 2013 another `qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=814772`

Comment: I just found another `http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=794004` copy of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/126684/47872 . The worst part of these sites which steal content is that they make it difficult to search for real solutions. So frustrating

Comment: This site continues to lift content from Ask Different - often within hours of questions arriving on the site.

Answer (score 10):

**ubuntuask.com**

- Copies from AskUbuntu - No attribution
- Example:
  `http://www.ubuntuask.com/q/answers-how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root-245201.html`
  copies
  `http://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root`

Answer (score 8):

**http://google-seo-help.blogspot.com/**

The entire site looks like it was copied, but the real clue was `http://google-seo-help.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-can-i-fetch-more-than-1000-google.html`, taken verbatim from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794141/453277

It's quite funny, because in the answer I use my own name repeatedly as sample data. The post is attributed to "Peter".

I can find no indication anywhere of the content's origin. It's not a big site, but it's a blatant ripoff.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

**blogosfera.co.uk**

- Looks like it targets SO specifically. The listing pages seem to link to the original sources, but the individual pages don't. No other mention of SO or any other source, the license, or attribution.
- No attribution
- No link back

#### Examples

- `http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2011/03/php-x86-how-to-get-filesize-of-2gb-file-without-external-program/`, original question: [PHP x86 How to get filesize of > 2 GB file without external program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501451/629493)
- `http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/implement-iqueryable-wrapper-to-translate-result-objects/` Note the lack of links to the original source ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365764/implement-iqueryable-wrapper-to-translate-result-objects)). However, if you go here: `http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/category/net-2/`, you should be able to find the same post, and the title will take you to the original source (click the date at the bottom to get to the individual post on the system).

Comment: Another example: www.blogosfera.co.uk/tag/wix-burn/ (original Stack Overflow question: *[Wix Burn: How to reboot after installing a MsuPackage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502480)*)

Answer (score 8):

### `http://nerdanswer.com/`

It has scrapes from various SE sites (Super User, Server Fault, Webmasters, …).

They link back to the question (e.g., "View full answer on Pro Webmasters") and the user profile, but …

- no attribution
- no mentioning that the content is licensed under CC BY-SA

#### Examples

- `http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=147786`
- `http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=32842`
- `http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=351177`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen See the [duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) for new instructions on reporting scrapers.

Comment: @michaelb958 thanks, email sent

Answer (score 8):

**zzzxo.com**

- Questions and answers appear to have usernames and profile images intact, but no links back to Stack Overflow anywhere.
- Alleges to be an Amazon Gold Box affiliate.

Examples:

---

- Original question: [How to work reliably with XmlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549593/how-to-work-reliably-with-xmlreader)
- Scraped question: `http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-how-to-work-reliably-with-xmlreader-15549593.html`

---

- Original question: [How to cross-compile OpenSSH for ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796291/how-to-cross-compile-openssh-for-arm)
- Scraped question: `http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-how-to-cross-compile-openssh-for-arm-15796291.html`

Comment: It appears that they copy everything from here. Not only some popular tags, no, everything. (I found even some of my stuff, does that mean I could send them a DCMA Notice?)

Comment: I googled my name `"Rocket Hazmat"` (keep the quotes), and this page was the 7th result.  Not just the question and answers, they are also copying user names AND avatars with no links to the source!  (Their scraper is pretty crappy, because their page shows that I posted 3 answers.  I didn't post any, I just happened to have been the last person to edit 3 of the answers!)

Answer (score 8):

**www.lovevideogame.com**

- Scrapes questions from Gaming/Arqade
- Displays completely different users for the questions/answer (seem to be non-SE users)
- No link back to the source
- Claims copyright:

  > COPYRIGHT © 2013 www.lovevideogame.com; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki

#### Examples

- [On Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100106/is-it-possible-to-use-a-different-folder-than-minecraft/100120#100120) and on LoveVideoGame: `www.lovevideogame.com/q/answers-is-it-possible-to-use-a-different-folder-than-minecraft-100106.html`
- `lovevideogame.com/q/answers-starcraft-1-disc-2-isnt-continuing-the-installation-126684.html` is a flagrant copy of [Starcraft 1 disc 2 isn't continuing the installation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/126684/47872) . No recognition whatsoever that this is StackExchange material. They even stole the profile pictures along with the usernames.

Answer (score 7):

**http://46424.com** ("IQwen question AND answer")

Example: [CSS3 Smooth Cross Browser Grayscale Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662675/css3-smooth-cross-browser-grayscale-image)
Bad Site: `http://46424.com/question/90111#.URlBC2fzLfW`

On the bad site, clicking most links (including those for OP name) takes you to pop-up hell.

Another example (originally posted by Josh Caswell):
`http://46424.com/question/458182#.URsgekVZpKM` is a copy of [Xcode: setTitle not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846393/xcode-settitle-not-working)

No attribution or links back to SO anywhere.

Comment: Looks like they copied [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4185657/866022) too `http://46424.com/question/F170810`

Comment: Just found another example. Googling for `hibernate add event listeners runtime` gives `http://46424.com/question/224732` as 6th result. It's an outdated scrapeoff of [Registering hibernate event listeners to annotated entities at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14062074/851811). No attribution anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

**`http://questiontrack.com`**

Is another screen scraper that doesn't reference SO.

**Example**

`http://questiontrack.com/flask-sqlalchemy-no-such-table-980892.html`

straight screen scrap from

[Flask-SQLALchemy: No such table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440605/flask-sqlalchemy-no-such-table)

Comment: Still there (http://questiontrack.com/can-i-switch-user-in-vagrant-bootstrap-shell-script-1157054.html)

Comment: Another sample: http://questiontrack.com/understanding-python-unicode-and-linux-terminal-986535.html

Answer (score 6):

#### fatalweb.com

- Example: fatalweb.com/questions/621876/should-i-upgrade-this-model-to-inheritance is a scrape of [should i upgrade this model to inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028195/should-i-upgrade-this-model-to-inheritance).
- No attribution or linkback to Stack Overflow; only mentions OP's username

Comment: Thanks for the report - these guys haven't improved and seem to have no intention of attributing, so their crawlers are now banned.

Answer (score 6):

#### codeblow.com

- Example: `http://codeblow.com/questions/good-ruby-on-rails-free-hosting` duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055682/good-ruby-on-rails-free-hosting.
- Does not visually indicate origin, does not link to the original question, does not show any author names, and therefore cannot hyperlink back to the user profile.
- Says *"Code Blow provides to you all the programmers knowledge of all programmers that took time to write answers to every question that you can find here. Feel free to ready and learn from all these informations."* - They acknowledge that it took time, but feel that it's OK to steal it? What gives?

Comment: Is there another example? I can;t see the SO question as it was deleted due to reasons of moderation.

Comment: Another example: http://codeblow.com/questions/oracle-row-change-time-stamp/ (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766390/oracle-row-change-time-stamp) (reported via email)

Comment: I hate the way this site automatically replaces some words.  It makes the questions and answers look dumb.

Comment: Another example: http://codeblow.com/questions/node-js-running-alongside-apache-php/

Answer (score 6):

**74ku.com**

- Example: `http://74ku.com/question/548720` (Copy of SO question [Comparing MongoDB and RethinkDB Bulk Insert Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151554/comparing-mongodb-and-rethinkdb-bulk-insert-performance))
- Questions do not have attribution
- There is no link to SO - anywhere as far as I can tell

*Updated [March 21, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172809/131713):*
The post below was copied from Stackoverflow.com. It mentions the SO user's ID but does not mention that it was copied from SO. It also does not link to the original post.

`http://74ku.com/question/149547`

*Updated May 17, 2013:*
According to the comments, it looks like this site is down, but it was apparently up in March, so...?

Comment: These guys now appear to be offline, will check again in a few days.

Comment: Yep, looks offline from here too.

Comment: Still looks down over a year later.

Comment: Possibly related to 9exceptions, reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173379/131713).

Answer (score 6):

`www.gp958.com` is a verbatim copy of the majority of content from [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) right down to the site's title tag, and linking images from stack.imgur.com. The copyright line at the bottom of each page says:

> © 2013 GP958 All rights reserved.

Which breaks our cc-wiki license.

Example:

`http://www.gp958.com/questions/44293.html` is a copy of [What does permission "MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44293/156)

There are no links back to the source site, there's no mention of where the content came from, the original authors names have been removed and replaced with "Guest".

Comment: Another example: `http://www.androidenth.com/q/answers-what-does-permission-manage-accounts-mean-44293.html`. At least they keep our user names plus avatars, and state CC-BY-SA as license, but do not seem to care for the BY of their source: I cannot find a link back to ASE, nor do I find ASE even mentioned (neither on their start page).

Answer (score 6):

This site copies the Stack Exchange site content (without following attribution guidelines)

**Site**: `http://t6942.codeinpro.us/`

**Example**

1. This `http://t6942.codeinpro.us/q/508112064f1eba38a4facfd7` is a copy of SO question [Finding path to plist in Xcode project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046370/finding-path-to-plist-in-xcode-project-folder)
2. This `http://t6942.codeinpro.us/q/5080d43e4f1eba38a49a7e8f` is a copy of Serverfault question [Can't resolve DNS only in one machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/88131/cant-resolve-dns-only-in-one-machine)
3. This `http://t6942.codeinpro.us/q/5080d46d4f1eba38a49ade6c` is a copy of Serverfault question [Reset crawled content for one content source in MOSS](https://serverfault.com/questions/116089/reset-crawled-content-for-one-content-source-in-moss)

---

I was able to link to one of the SO questions(which I answered) copied by this site: `http://www.ggkf.com/`. This came up as the first result in Google search results.

[image]

**SO Question**: [CGImageRelease Error in architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827531/cgimagerelease-error-in-architecture-i386)

**Copy link**: `http://www.ggkf.com/ios/cgimagerelease-error-in-architecture-i386`

The list of many such copied questions can be found on this site.

Answer (score 5):

**`http://www.genealogyqa.co.uk/`**

As far as I can see, this site is copying every question and answer verbatim from [Genealogy.SE](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/). There is no attribution present.

Example:

`http://www.genealogyqa.co.uk/q/answers-what-is-the-value-of-recording-the-witnesses-of-a-baptism-or-marriage-3481.html`

[What is the value of recording the witnesses of a baptism or marriage?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3481/56)

Answer (score 5):

**http://codeinpro.us**

- Questions are not linked back to Stack Overflow
- No attribution whatsoever
- Names of the poster are not shown.

Found as a result of `http://t1688.codeinpro.us/q/5080e9cc4f1eba38a4be9188` versus [When should I use the "strictfp" keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java/16959752#16959752)

`http://t6803.codeinpro.us/q/508116df4f1eba38a4022725` from [Copy current selection on hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592545/copy-current-selection-on-hotkey/)

Comment: Duplicate answer of http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184723/178687. Recommend deletion to reduce clutter?

Comment: @nneonneo I think you posted that in the wrong place... That link is *this* answer.

Comment: Whoops, I meant http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187690/178687.

Answer (score 5):

**`3mr.me`** is scraping at least Stack Overflow and English Language & Usage without following attribution rules.

For example,

- `http://3mr.me/what-is-the-origin-of-the-slang-kicks-meaning-sneakers/`
- `http://3mr.me/how-to-copy-the-current-file-full-name-to-global-clipboard-in-vim/`
- `http://3mr.me/what-does-the-term-empirical-praxis-mean/`

are scrapes of:

- `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125733/what-is-the-origin-of-the-slang-kicks-meaning-sneakers`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755682/how-to-copy-the-current-file-full-name-to-global-clipboard-in-vim`
- `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132261/what-does-the-term-empirical-praxis-mean`

without (1) visually indicating that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User [etc.] in some way; (2) hyperlinking directly to the original question on the source site; or (4) hyperlinking each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site.

For (2), they are linking back ("Read More Details"), but are both using tinyurl and nofollow, so it's not a [direct link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

They have this in the footer, but it doesn't meet SE attribution requirements:

> © 2013 3mr.me. All rights reserved.
>
> Except for third party materials and otherwise stated, this content is made available under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 2.0 Licence. The original Author/Publisher name is mentioned above.

Comment: Me too. I found my question popping to the top of google search on their site within 2 hours of posting it.

Comment: @MattEllen: See the linked duplicate for new instructions on reporting duplicates, please.

Answer (score 4):

#### need-programmer.blogspot.com

- Example (`http://need-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-use-subqueries-in-sqlalchemy-to.html`) (Copy of SO question [How to use subqueries in SQLAlchemy to produce a moving average?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764358/how-to-use-subqueries-in-sqlalchemy-to-produce-a-moving-averag))
- Questions do not have attribution
- Link to Stack Overflow question is nofollow

Answer (score 3):

`http://cloudfront.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-nagios-on-ubuntu-1204.html#.UYweEdcX63c`

**Original:**

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145518/how-do-i-install-nagios
```

Didn't even bother to upload the images somewhere else, they still point to stack.imgur.

Comment: i will say, it's flattering to find someone stealing my stuff. it's also sad.

Answer (score 3):

**answerstravel.co.uk**

- A clear scraped version of Travel-SE, with copied verbatim questions and answers
- There's no attribution, no links to the original content, no ToS or any contact information on the site.
- Plastered with Amazon adverts
- Example: `http://www.answerstravel.co.uk/q/answers-what-to-do-in-las-vegas-without-having-to-sin-18147.html` without linking to [the original question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/what-to-do-in-las-vegas-without-having-to-sin).

**answershistory.co.uk**

- Verbatim copies of [History.SE's](https://history.stackexchange.com/) questions and answers, without attribution
- Example: `http://www.answershistory.co.uk/q/answers-when-and-why-was-seleucia-ultimately-abandoned-9010.html` is a copy of [When and why was Seleucia ultimately abandoned?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9010/when-and-why-was-seleucia-ultimately-abandoned)
- Appeared higher than History.SE in [this search query](https://www.google.gr/search?q=black-invisibilty%20factor&oq=black&aqs=chrome.1.57j59l2j0.3219j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ([original question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/9111/in-the-hills-beyond-is-there-a-black-invisibilty-factor))

Answer (score 2):

#### SoftwareTalk.info

- Example (`http://www.softwaretalk.info/how-can-i-start-from-page-1-again-on-the-4th-page-of-my-ms-word-document.htm`) (Original on SU: [How can I start from page 1 again, on the 4th page of my MS Word document?](https://superuser.com/questions/204639/how-can-i-start-from-page-1-again-on-the-4th-page-of-my-ms-word-document))
- Gives credit to users and links to their profiles
- Main Super User attribution link is nofollow

Answer (score 2):

#### bicycles.vniup.com, b.vniup.com, and www.vniup.com

- content on bicycles is from [Bicycles.SE] (I recognized it) and content on www sure looks like it's from other SE sites
- In addition, there is scraped content from:

  - [CSTheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://vniup.com/index.php/category/computer-science/`)
  - [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/english-learning`)
  - [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/electronic`)
  - [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/gamer`)
  - [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/geographic-information-system`)
  - [Home Improvement/DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/house-improvement`)
  - [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/physics`)
  - [Sharepoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/sharepoint`)
  - [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://b.vniup.com/index.php/category/text-and-document`)
  - [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/) (see `http://vniup.com/index.php/category/ubuntu`)
  - [AskDifferent.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (though it seems to be only [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35196/jailbroken-iphone-stuck-on-boot-screen/35199#35199) repeated over and over...)
  - [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (see `http://vniup.com/index.php/linux-unix/`)
- The categories on vniup.com itself seem to be scraping some of the larger Ubuntu tag feeds.
- Shows names of answerers, but not askers. There is no further attribution to SE or any indication that the site is not providing original content.

**Edit:**

- Can't see any attribution what-so-ever on the site, not even usernames

Answer (score 2):

**linuxine.com**

- copies from askubuntu.com and unix.stackexchange.com
- the only reference to SE is a discrete, indirect link back to the original post
- all user information stripped

Example: `http://www.linuxine.com/story/alt-tab-does-not-display-all-applications` is a clone of [Alt-tab does not display all applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129079/alt-tab-does-not-display-all-applications)

It also appears higher in google search results than askubuntu.com (for example, see https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+why+do+I+not+see+skype+in+alt-tab&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs#q=ubuntu+why+do+I+not+see+skype+in+alt-tab&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=xQb&channel=fs&prmd=imvns&ei=i8zXT5vAA8jA2gWinMW9Dw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=eb77e84dac2421f&biw=1515&bih=993)

Comment: There is a reference to AskUbuntu.com, right at the beginning of the q.

Comment: @HodofHod: I'd say this is just on the wrong side of the borderline. It has a link back to the original question and (barely) mentions AskUbuntu, but fails the [other two tests that Jeff has laid out](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: I have banned their scraper from hitting us, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**http://www.binrand.com/**

- Example (`http://www.binrand.com/post/2965287-check-thiscall-getting-an-access-violation-error-is-c-while-calling-the-c.html`)
- Entire site, even some CSS
- No attribution, no single mention of SO
- No hyperlinks

Answer (score 2):

**http://joomla.it2y.info/**

- Example (http://joomla.it2y.info/using-locale-date-format-in-joomla-modules.html) is a direct copy of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097480/using-locale-date-format-in-joomla-modules)
- I checked several Joomla articles. All of them were from StackOverflow.
- This site has many categories of questions. Others might also be copied from StackOVerflow, although a quick check suggests they copy from many other sites.
- No hint the question and answer came from StackOverflow.
- No link to StackOverflow.

Comment: Also using www.it2y.info: http://www.it2y.info/windows/how-to-avoid-12-seconds-delay-when-disonnecting-from-share-in-windows-7.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Huntanswer.com

- Questions link back to Stack Overflow (no follow)
- Example `http://huntanswer.com/question/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-api/` links back to original at [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479709/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-api)
- All questions are attributed to `hunt answer`.
- Only questions are copied, answers are left out.

Answer (score 2):

**http://www.ubun2.com**

- Example: `http://www.ubun2.com/question/893/no_bios_no_video_after_updates` which is a copy of question `http://askubuntu.com/questions/29733/no-bios-no-video-after-ubuntu-updates` in Ask Ubuntu.
- The questions do not have any attribution to the contents in Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Not only that, but because the domain name is phonetically equivalent to "ubuntu", it would likely fall under trademark infringement under most jurisdictions. I filled in the form on Canonical's website letting them know about this and they have indicated that they are looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

### www.ofcodeprogramming.com

Orginal Question: [Android : Custom Shapes (Behaviour of layer-list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050751/android-custom-shapes-behaviour-of-layer-list)
And its clone `http://www.ofcodeprogramming.com/14777/android-custom-shapes-behaviour-of-layer-list`

There is not any contibuting to the author or Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

#### yulebiao.com

- Question2Answer Serving the latest DB dumps
- No link back to SO
- Authors are not mentioned or linked
- Site has malware / rogue JS issues so be wary, example link: `http://www.yulebiao.com/questions/15571503/multiple-tables-for-addresses-serving-multiple-purposes`

It looks like someone wrote a connector to import our dumps right into Question2Answer, but it doesn't handle the attribution requirements. Additionally, the site might be compromised - so be wary when visiting.

Comment: Just found one of my answers on that site without any mention of who posted the answer, so was coming here to report it.

Answer (score 2):

**http://bugsort.com**

Reproduces content from all over the Stack Exchange network without attribution to the authors or the site.

---

Example from [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com):

> [Internal moment in the hull of a pressure vessel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55189/internal-moment-in-the-hull-of-a-pressure-vessel)

On the site:

```
http://bugsort.com/magical-science/physics-internal-moment-in-the-hull-of-a-pressure-vessel/
```

---

Example from [Super User](http://superuser.com):

> [What is the difference between striping BYTES and BLOCKS using RAID?](https://superuser.com/questions/570818/what-is-the-difference-between-striping-bytes-and-blocks-using-raid)

On the site:

```
http://bugsort.com/computer-users/computer-what-is-the-difference-between-striping-bytes-and-blocks-usin-77941/
```

Answer (score 2):

#### androiddev.orkitra.com

Scraping questions and answers from the android tag with no attribution and not even mentioning the users who asked and answered the questions.

For example

`http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=43463`

is sourced from:

[Trying to requery an already closed cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192728/trying-to-requery-an-already-closed-cursor)

Answer (score 2):

**earthwithsun.com**

Example here: `http://earthwithsun.com/questions/600268/how-to-automatically-change-network-adapter-settings-upon-new-network` (copied from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/600268/how-to-automatically-change-network-adapter-settings-upon-new-network))

Only reference to SU/SE are the links in the question's last paragraph (by the original author on SU) and the image from `i.stack.imgur.com` in the answer.

Comment: This site is still reposting SU content w/o attribution.  I found this meta thread while searching for more information after experiencing deja vu while reading that site after an identical SU thread.  Substitute their domain name on any SU thread URL to see an example.

Answer (score 2):

**errors.bz**

Original question: [mkfs.ext4 is taking hours to complete on 4 TB RAID 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/267393/mkfs-ext4-is-taking-hours-to-complete-on-4tb-raid-5)

Copied content: `http://errors.bz/Questions/mkfs-ext4-is-taking-hours-to-complete-on-4TB-raid-5-63638.html`

The website appears to be scraping all content from Server Fault and not giving any attribution what-so-ever.

Answer (score 2):

**faithfulnews.com**

`http://www.faithfulnews.com/main/sub_category/140/questions-christianity-questions-bible-questions`

copies from http://Christianity.Stackexchange.com. It links back to original posts for questions, but not answers, and does not include usernames. It does not indicate content is from SE.

Comment: I [mentioned this on their facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=10151834827919673&id=179544464672) and they have now taken this page down. I also recommended that they review the licensing of all of their other aggregated content.

Answer (score 2):

**`http://www.wdailynews.com/`**

Takes SO content whole hog.

`http://www.wdailynews.com/mysql/migrating-from-mysql-to-mariadb-and-viceversa.html`

straight screen scrap from

[Migrating from MySQL to MariaDB and viceversa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224145/migrating-from-mysql-to-mariadb-and-viceversa)

Answer (score 2):

**`http://www.ggkf.com/`**

Yet another one.

I actually came across it due to a spamming user who posted a link to their site twice in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484104/support-offline-data-display-in-ios-app/18506913 (10k only) with that link being to *their copy of that question*.

Checking out their home page today, they seem to be getting stuff pretty quickly; probably using the API. They also have Disqus comments active, and seem to get a bit of activity there, so they are apparently getting hits through from Google.

Answer (score 2):

**jjeasy.com**

Scrapes answers from Server Fault without attribution.

Example: `http://www.jjeasy.com/best-strategypractices-for-devtestprod-server/` is lifted from [Best strategy/practices for Dev/Test/Prod Server](https://serverfault.com/q/137830/126632) with no attribution for Server Fault or the question or answer authors, nor is the license given.

Answer (score 1):

#### phpmagister.com

- seems to be a scrape of stackoverflow.com's PHP tagged questions
- no attribution at all
- all questions attributed to username 'Stacked'
- no links to stackexchange.com
- very spammy (popups, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

***.phpfogapp.com**

Subsite: javascriptfaq.phpfogapp.com, titled "Javascript FAQ"

Example: `http://javascriptfaq.phpfogapp.com/javascript-why-create-loops-to-get-elements-for-events.html`

Content has been stolen from Stack Overflow, but only the questions related to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). Answers are posted as comments, with original names of the users who answered, but without links to the users or to Stack Overflow.

They also copied the "Demo" links of `jsfiddle.net` with the original answers. There is also a button marked "Submit a comment," but it doesn't work for commenting.

*Update [August 3, 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142097/131713):*

Subsite: javascriptask.phpfogapp.com

This site seems to actively crawl or collect JavaScript questions from SO. It **violates all attributions** but mentions the authors' names. There are no links to original questions or to author profiles, or any indication that the posts are from Stack Overflow.

Example: `http://javascriptask.phpfogapp.com/php-http-status-code-with-special-characters-in-the-url.html`

Answer (score 1):

**boardreader.com**

Doesn't respect the fourth requirement :

> Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site

Example :

`http://boardreader.com/thread/What_can_cause_CICS_transaction_to_write_oy3hwX5d0dy.html`

Only 3/5 author profiles are linked.

Real post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9005110/1140748).

Answer (score 1):

**www.superbank.org**

There are only references to author names. **No links to Stack Overflow are available, and nothing indicates that the content is from SO.**

Example:

`http://www.superbank.org/is-the-garbage-first-g1-collector-production-ready-in-java-6/`

"Real" question: [Is the garbage-first (G1) collector "production ready" in Java 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9689728/1140748).

*Updated [October 16, 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148963/131713):*
Appeared on the [second page of Google results](https://www.google.com#q=spring+3.1.2+register+%22MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter%22) for `spring 3.1.2 register "MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"`.

No attribution. `http://www.superbank.org/help/34975/registrer-mappingjackson2httpmessageconverter-in-spring-3-1-2-with-jaxb-annotati.html` is a copy of [Registrer MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in Spring 3.1.2 with JAXB annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514285/registrer-mappingjackson2httpmessageconverter-in-spring-3-1-2-with-jaxb-annotati).

Answer (score 1):

**ifmdb.com**

Here is a description from the site, a pretty murky looking, badly designed FAQ page:

> IFMDb is searchable database of messages which are legally posted on the internet forums by internet community, for internet community

To try to illustrate the cc-wiki breach, let's take for example `http://android.ifmdb.com/IsEBDg6p0-set-a-new-views-margins-programatically.html`. This page does not break attribution requirement **1**, since there is a reference to StackOverflow (albeit not-hyperlinked). What is does breach is **2**, as the link to the "*full question*" is a proxy between the original clone site and StackOverflow, e.g. `http://android.ifmdb.com/fullpost-IsEBDg6p0.html` has a `nofollow` and doesn't link back.

Furthermore, I believe **3** is breached as well, as only *Unknown* shows up as the author. To round it all up, **4** is not respected, as there is no reference to the original account from StackOverflow which originated the question – original question is here

Sure hope my assertions are ok.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**http://www.webmasterbeta.net**

I found a copy of my question ( [How to De-Authenticate a Windows Auth user with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000014/how-to-de-authenticate-a-windows-auth-user-with-php) ) over here: `http://www.webmasterbeta.net/Thread-How-to-De-Authenticate-a-Windows-Auth-user-with-PHP`

Answer (score 1):

**www.techerald.com**

- Rough translation into other languages (like German), might be Google translator.
- Links that are part of text or users are kept: go directly and visible to Stack Overflow sites etc.
- example: `http://de.techerald.com/page/como-puedo-deshabilitar-resharper-en-vs-y-habilitar-de-nuevo.html`
- **Update:** *On bottom of example is written (in German): This comes originally from this question (linked) on www.stackoverflow.com (linked).* Thus it might *not* be a real misuse/ stealing.

Answer (score 1):

**9nit.com**

Sample: 
`http://www.9nit.com/windows/how-to-get-fully-qualified-domain-name-on-windows-in-delphi-107009.html`

Comment: All link was abandoned rel = 'nofollow' please be considered. thanks you

Answer (score 1):

**efreedom.com**

Sample: `http://efreedom.com/Question/1-9792411/Get-Windows-Domain-Name`

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58369/204869).

Answer (score 1):

**javaproblems.hopto.org**

Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616855/how-do-i-setup-jogl-with-netbeans

Duplicate: `http://javaproblems.hopto.org/how-do-i-setup-jogl-with-netbeans/`

Violations:

- Does not show author name; does not hyperlink author name
- Stack Overflow attribution is not clearly established

  - Link is in plain-text
  - Blurb does not identify that content came from SO, merely that you can find an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

**plantware.net**

Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616855/how-do-i-setup-jogl-with-netbeans

Duplicate: `http://plantware.net/questions/14616855/how-do-i-setup-jogl-with-netbeans`

Violations:

- No mention of or link to Stack Overflow question.
- Does not show author name.

The site's front page is a huge listing of many other similar questions and tags that look like they were simply ripped from SO.

Answer (score 1):

**9exceptions.com**

The post below was copied from Stackoverflow.com. It mentions the SO user's ID but does not mention that it was copied from SO. It also does not link to the original post.

`http://9exception.com/question/149547`

Comment: Possibly related to 74ku, reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169610/131713).

Answer (score 1):

**www.diy101.net**

- Example: `http://www.diy101.net/questions/5809/any-words-of-advice-on-dealing-with-termites`

  - Copy of: [Any words of advice on dealing with termites?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/any-words-of-advice-on-dealing-with-termites)
- Licensing terms and other footer contents are removed
- About page claims to be part of **Stack Exchange Network**

Answer (score 1):

**FantasyPublishings.com/morePHPHelp/**

`http://www.fantasypublishings.com/morePhpHelp/How_to_enable_the_new_ObjectiveC_object_literals_on_iOS__Stack_Overflow_page64447.php` is a copy of [How to enable the new Objective-C object literals on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658669/how-to-enable-the-new-objective-c-object-literals-on-ios)

Comment: `Stack_Overflow_page64447.php` smoooooth

Answer (score 1):

**`http://2exception.com/`**

The first question I see there is: `http://2exception.com/question/5764`

SO original: [how to slow down the speed of buffer sending java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103215/how-to-slow-down-the-speed-of-buffer-sending-java)

Second: http://2exception.com/question/5762

Original: [How to specify relative path for image in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103463/how-to-specify-relative-path-for-image-in-xsl)

et cetera. 
Answers are copied, too. Links to profiles changed to some links on 2exception.com but those are broken. Found no attribution whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

#### cloverink.net

Scraping/copying questions with accepted answers and passing off as blog material. No attribution of any sort.

For example

`http://cloverink.net/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c/`

is sourced from:

[Can a Byte[] Array be written to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c)

Site even has Disqus comments set up and people are commenting on these bogus posts, for example:

`http://cloverink.net/invalid-multibyte-char-us-ascii-with-rails-and-ruby-1-9`

Comment: People are just getting more rude... wonder if there's any legal way to shut such sites down?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - did ask Tim Post about whether the SE team actively pursue these sites and apparently they do. It just takes time. But yes, downright rude.

Answer (score 1):

**askoverflow.com**

I once asked [Is Ask Overflow a part of the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178247/askoverflow-is-this-a-part-of-stack-exchange-network) about the fake site Ask Overflow, so I am adding this answer for that fake site.

I don't know whether it violates the attribution rules, though.

Answer (score 1):

**`http://088062.com/`**

- No attribution at all
- proxying the whole site
- Nice translation of everything into German (working better than I'd expected)
- User names get removed from the posts (but their accounts are accessible via the right URI)

Answer (score 1):

**codequestions.org**

Apparently 100% duplicating site, doesn't even properly include answers on many of them... no attribution.

Original:
[saving images in python at a very high quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183462/saving-images-in-python-at-a-very-high-quality)

`http://codequestions.org/saving-images-in-python-at-a-very-high-quality/`

Second:
[ASP MVC 2 Forgot Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616928/asp-mvc-2-forgot-password)

`http://codequestions.org/asp-mvc-2-forgot-password/`

Answer (score 1):

`http://asilvia12-silviaa.blogspot.fr/`

Posts questions from multiple SE sites, e.g. `http://asilvia12-silviaa.blogspot.fr/2013/06/creating-multiple-devices-from-one.html` from [Creating multiple devices from one device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78086/creating-multiple-devices-from-one-device/78102), `https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101807/tags-404-error-when-associating-tag-with-post` from [Using SPM5 with MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923014/using-spm5-with-matlab), `https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101807/tags-404-error-when-associating-tag-with-post` from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101807/tags-404-error-when-associating-tag-with-post etc.

No attribution.

I noticed it in Google results, but it wasn't high-ranking.

Warning: don't go there with JS on, the ads are especially annoying.

Answer (score 1):

**incoupo.com**

Copy from [TEX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) without attribution.

- Example `http://www.incoupo.com/q/answers-gnuplot-ubuntu-12-10-kile-texlive2012-103168.html`, Original [gnuplot, ubuntu 12.10, kile, texlive2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103168/gnuplot-ubuntu-12-10-kile-texlive2012)
- No mentioning that this material is from SE
- No hyperlink to original question
- No hyperlinks to user names

Answer (score 1):

**www.vvreview.com**

Appears to be scraping Server Fault (among other sites).

`http://www.vvreview.com/q/answers-controlling-tomcat-with-supervisor-425132.html` ← [Controlling tomcat with supervisor](https://serverfault.com/questions/425132/controlling-tomcat-with-supervisor)

`http://www.vvreview.com/q/answers-supervisor-always-quit-process-with-exit-status-0-not-expected-163392.html` ← [Supervisor always quit process with 'exit status 0; not expected'](https://serverfault.com/questions/163392/supervisor-always-quit-process-with-exit-status-0-not-expected)

Answer (score 1):

**www.cryptoanswers.co.uk**

Reposts many (all?) questions from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ with no attribution (there's an author name, which isn't always correct, but no mention of Stack Exchange and no link back).

Examples:

- `http://www.cryptoanswers.co.uk/q/answers-is-this-authenticated-one-way-communication-protocol-secure-2414.html` = [Is this authenticated one-way communication protocol secure?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/is-this-authenticated-one-way-communication-protocol-secure)
- `http://www.cryptoanswers.co.uk/q/answers-difference-entity-authentication-vs-implicit-key-authentication-8484.html` = [Difference entity authentication and implicit key authentication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8484/difference-entity-authentication-vs-implicit-key-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

**abbate-zara2jan1991.blogspot.fr**

Reposts content from various Stack Exchange sites with no attribution.

Examples:

- `http://abbate-zara2jan1991.blogspot.fr/2013/05/difference-entity-authentication-vs.html` = [Difference entity authentication and implicit key authentication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8484/difference-entity-authentication-vs-implicit-key-authentication)
- `http://abbate-zara2jan1991.blogspot.fr/2013/05/elegant-approach-to-solve-nlgn-106.html` = [Elegant way to solve $n\log_2(n) \le 10^6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406707/elegant-way-to-solve-n-log-2n-le-106)
- `http://abbate-zara2jan1991.blogspot.fr/2013/05/generically-typed-interface.html` = [Generically typed interface](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26754/generically-typed-interface)

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.zzzxo.com/`

No notice that content is from Stack Overflow. No links to original question. Does identify original author. Does not link back to original author's profile.

Also appears to be scraping the related questions links.

Appears to be using the site as a giant advertising board for an Amazon Associate account. Not sure if there's a way to report that to Amazon...

Examples:

- `http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-generated-docset-causes-xcode-4-6-crash-15947507.html` is [Generated DocSet causes Xcode 4.6 crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947507/generated-docset-causes-xcode-4-6-crash)
- `http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-if-or-shorter-way-16910305.html` is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910305/if-or-shorter-way

Answer (score 1):

**http://www.codeloopers.com**

- Questions are not linked back to Stack Overflow
- No attribution whatsoever
- Names of the poster are replaced by: webqueen ( a whooping 22 posts), david_2007, and their common friend er.James. Sukrut seems to be a human person.
- a few genuine posts in the PHP section
- one or two questions and their answers in each section of the forum to make it look alive.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.pmanswers.co.uk/`

Exact copy of posts from [PMSE](http://pm.stackexchange.com).

On this site, I didn't see the following (maybe I missed it):

- Visual indication that the content is from Stack Exchange.
- Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site.
- Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site.

Answer (score 1):

From: ['Mirrors' of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187661/mirrors-of-stackoverflow)

`http://www.9nit.com/c-c-/opencv-imwrite-saving-complete-black-jpeg-37967.html`

`http://fatalweb.com/question/change-cvfindcontours-to-4-connected-neighbors-from-8-connected-6951483.html`

`http://www.rqna.net/qna/kvqnun-how-to-minimize-opencv-library-size.html`

`http://www.questiondb.com/questions/7403455/how-do-you-set-up-opencv-with-qt-in-osx`

`http://it.dbline.net/questions/tagged/contour?page=1&sort=active http://s7438.socode.info/question/5081280a4f1eba38a41a813d`

Comment: Thank you @manishearth

Comment: 9nit.com they link the original source web page .e author names for every question and answer
Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username) .Eg: http://www.9nit.com/apache/mod_rewrite-keeps-anchor-link-138415.html

Comment: @user216457 There is no clear visual indication: `You will ensure that any such use of Subscriber Content visually displays or otherwise indicates the source of the Subscriber Content as coming from the Stack Exchange Network. This requirement is satisfied with a discreet text blurb, or some other unobtrusive but clear visual indication.`

Answer (score 1):

`www.faqoverflow.com`

- example: `www.faqoverflow.com/stackoverflow/122102.html` copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: Now appears to be attributing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**eonlinegratis.com**

Copies from SuperUser, ServerFault and perhaps others. They even file it on their main page under those names, along with a few other sites.  No attribution to any of them.

**Examples:**

- `http://www.eonlinegratis.com/2013/equivalent-for-xev-on-windows/` copies [Equivalent for xev on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/348070/equivalent-for-xev-on-windows)
- `http://www.eonlinegratis.com/2013/how-do-i-hide-meeting-attendees-in-outlook-2010/` copies [How do I hide meeting attendees in Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/451034/how-do-i-hide-meeting-attendees-in-outlook-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Another one: `http://www.2exception.com/`

Answer (score 1):

I found this result quite high in my search-query just now
`http://questiontrack.com/does-php-validate-requests-against-a-wsdl-prior-to-sending-the-request-1031924.html`  (with origional: [Does PHP Validate Requests Against a WSDL Prior to Sending the Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243837/does-php-validate-requests-against-a-wsdl-prior-to-sending-the-request) )

There wasn't a hit on a search within this question for questiontrack, so therefore:

- `http://questiontrack.com` seems to copy not only stackoverflow questions, but others as well

Comment: It came up as the bottom three hits on the first page for a search I just did, all of which are from SO (to be fair, for two of the three, the SO link shows up at the top of the first page of Google hits).

Answer (score 1):

**chanhope.com**

- No indication content comes from Stack Exchange
- No link back to original question
- No author names
- No author profile links

Examples

- `chanhope.com/discussions/how-to-reply-to-facebook-messages-using-gmail.html`

  From [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/reply-to-facebook-message-via-email)
- `chanhope.com/discussions/how-to-split-up-the-wordpress-blog-post-title-and-insert-a-span-tag.html`

  From [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45589/how-to-split-up-the-title-and-insert-a-span-tag)
- `chanhope.com/discussions/how-to-group-apps-in-unity-launcher.html`

  From [Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227146/how-to-group-apps-in-unity-launcher?noredirect=1), [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81732/can-i-put-more-applications-in-a-unity-icon/227157#227157)
- `chanhope.com/discussions/multiple-submit-buttons-in-an-html-form.html`

  From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48/multiple-submit-buttons-in-an-html-form)

Answer (score 1):

**www.windowslinuxosx.com**

- Copies questions and answers from SU without any attribution. There is no indication on the site that the content came from SU.
- Examples:

  - `http://www.windowslinuxosx.com/q/answers-vim-can-i-disable-continuation-of-comments-to-the-next-line-271023.html` is [Vim: can I disable continuation of comments to the next line?](https://superuser.com/questions/271023/vim-can-i-disable-continuation-of-comments-to-the-next-line)
  - `http://www.windowslinuxosx.com/q/answers-my-ram-sticks-got-wet-can-i-still-use-them-641532.html` is [My RAM / memory sticks got wet, can I still use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/641532/my-ram-sticks-got-wet-can-i-still-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

`languageusage.com` is scraping “English Language & Usage” without following attribution rules.

For example,

> `http://www.languageusage.com/q/answers-neutral-term-for-a-person-in-the-same-organization-50864.html`

is a scrape of

> `http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50864/neutral-term-for-a-person-in-the-same-organization`

without attributing to SE, linking back to the question at SE, or linking back to the author at SE.

Answer (score 1):

**pressingquestion.com**

There is author attribution, but not post attribution if *the OP no longer exists*.

Example:

- www.pressingquestion.com/160637/What-Is-A-Good-Implementation-Of-A-Peer-To-Peer-Chat-Program-With-A-Server-For-Assigning-Connections-In-C%2B%2B%3F

Answer (score 1):

This site copies the Stack Exchange site content (without following attribution guidelines)

**Site**: `http://programmers-question.com`

**Example**

1. This `http://programmers-question.com/xcode-5-crashes-with-svn-version-1-7-xcode-svn-crash-xcode5/` is a copy of SO question [Xcode 5 crashes with SVN version 1.7 - self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890986/xcode-5-crashes-with-svn-version-1-7-self-signed-certificate)
2. This `http://programmers-question.com/how-to-stop-timer-on-killing-app-android-android-timer/` is a copy of SO question [How to stop timer on killing app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047941/how-to-stop-timer-on-killing-app-android)
3. This `http://programmers-question.com/objective-c-remove-navigationbars-bottom-border-ios7-objective-c-uinavigationbar-ios7-xcode5/` is a copy of SO question [Remove Navigationbar's bottom border iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047286/remove-navigationbars-bottom-border-ios7)

The list of many such copied questions can be found on this site.

Answer (score 1):

`http://www.unixli.com/q/answers-skip-all-new-device-drivers-in-make-oldconfig-for-linux-kernel-65758.html`

plagiarized from [Skip all new device drivers in `make oldconfig` for Linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65758/skip-all-new-device-drivers-in-make-oldconfig-for-linux-kernel)

No Stackexchange link on that site.

Answer (score 1):

http://jjask.com is pretty blatant with no attribution (that I could find).

[goddady domain pointed at external vps/plesk, subdomains do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719053/goddady-domain-pointed-at-external-vps-plesk-subdomains-do-not-work)

http://www.jjask.com/95053/goddady-domain-pointed-external-plesk-subdomains-not-work

and many more

Answer (score 1):

**zzcoupon.com**

- Uses content from Mathematics.SE.
- Includes advertisements alongside content.
- No mention of Stack Exchange as far as I can tell; lacks link to original author.
- ID in URL matches that of copied content.

A few examples:

- [A simple example of an uncountable set that is not R](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511751) copied at `http://www.zzcoupon.com/q/answers-a-simple-example-of-an-uncountable-set-that-is-not-mathbbr-511751.html`
- [Can the limit of a product exist if neither of its factors exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513822) copied at `http://www.zzcoupon.com/q/answers-can-the-limit-of-a-product-exist-if-neither-of-its-factors-exist-513822.html`
- [A series related to ζ(3).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510363) copied at `http://www.zzcoupon.com/q/answers-a-series-related-to-zeta-3-510363.html`

Comment: It lacks MathJAX too! Looks pretty atrocious

Answer (score 0):

#### unobaord.com & coderesource.org

- Links to the Stack Overflow main page (no follow)

Answer (score 0):

#### Globberstack.com

- No older posts. Assuming MSO post is accurate (new posts adhere to rules and are no follow)

Answer (score 0):

#### developerquestion.com

- Links to Stack Overflow question (no follow)

Answer (score 0):

#### johnnycoder.com

- Example (`http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/11/10/run-cmdexe-as-local-system-account/`)
- It looks like for this one, the person who posted it also has his own blog and posted the question there. He doesn’t link to us or any of the people on Stack Overflow who answered, but he doesn’t quote that text either - looks like he was just trying to get other answers from his readers.

Answer (score 0):

#### apacheserver.net ("Best unofficial Apache Server developers community")

- Question links redirect to homepage, on which I can’t figure out what’s happening.

Answer (score 0):

#### drija.com

- Example (`http://drija.com/multiple-monitors/54867/how-to-move-an-applications-dialog-box-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-the-main/`)
- This is a copy of the SU question [How to move an application's dialog box from a disconnected monitor to the main](https://superuser.com/questions/187176/how-to-move-an-applications-dialog-box-from-a-disconnected-monitor-to-the-), which links to another super user question (it includes a link to the second super user question, but not the one it copies)
- Does not indicate the post came from Stack Exchange
- Lists and includes links to asker and answerers

Answer (score 0):

#### questionhub.com

- Example (`http://www.questionhub.com/StackOverflow/1341075`)
- Aggregates Q&A’s from all around the web
- Format: copies text of question, then links to our question as the answer
- Does indicate that it came from Stack Overflow (logo in corner)
- Hyperlinks to our question
- Links to user who asked question and displays their name (bottom of page says “Post X days ago by ___”)
- Does not link to users who answered - but they don’t display the text of answers either (their answer is a link to our question)

Comment: It appears that they are compliant now, both questions and answers listed, with links to users, SO, all without `nofollow`.

Answer (score 0):

#### genmaint.com

- Example (`http://www.genmaint.com/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery.html`)
- Note: they describe themselves as “A collaboratively edited question and answer site.”
- Indicates it came from Stack Overflow
- Links back to original post and user profiles

Answer (score 0):

#### fr.w3support.net

- Example (`http://fr.w3support.net/index.php?db=su&amp;id=9811`)
- Doesn’t acknowledge it came from Stack Overflow, link to Stack Overflow, or any of our user profiles

Answer (score 0):

#### lampcms.com

- Question is attributed properly
- Answers are attributed to users, but not directly to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

#### nujk.com

- Example (`http://www.nujk.com/timer-job-from-a-spweb`) ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772508/timer-job-from-a-spweb))
- copies the adzerk divs, that is the only attribution
- mangles usernames

Answer (score 0):

#### ency9.com

- Example (`http://www.ency9.com/gadget/indexing-for-google-scholar-which-tags-to-use/`) (Original on Webmasters SE: [Indexing for Google scholar, which tags to use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/indexing-for-google-scholar-which-tags-to-us))
- no mention of Stack Overflow anywhere on the site
- no usernames at all, let alone credit to Stack Exchange users

Answer (score 0):

#### news.puppin.org

- Example (`http://news.puppin.org/question/non-relational-db-which-one-is-the-right-choice-closed/`) (Copy of SO post [Non-relational db, which one is the right choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808930/non-relational-db-which-one-is-the-right-choice))
- No attribution or link of any kind

Answer (score 0):

#### streamreader.org

- Gives attribution to users and links to their Gaming Stack Exchange profiles
- Does not link to the Gaming Stack Exchange question
- Mangles some of the text even

Answer (score 0):

#### sharepointqanda.com

- No attribution at all whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

#### iappnow.com

- no attribution at all
- “Continue here” link is broken (seems to direct to some original source)
- there is a `<link rel=”stackoverflow.com/...>` in the page source but it doesn’t seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

#### gardenquestions.com

- has an attrib link at the bottom claiming to get content from the Stack Exchange data dump
- no credit to users or link to the question

Answer (score 0):

#### jqpoint.com

- links back to the Stack Exchange question, but nofollow
- no asker or answerer attrib

Answer (score 0):

#### applerr.com

- no reference to SO or SE in any way
- no attribution to users
- does not post the answer
- claims its own copyright on the content!

Answer (score 0):

#### www.aspwinhost.com

- changing names of the users
- replacing links of users to a single Indian site
- claims copyright on the content

Answer (score 0):

#### answerleaks.com

- Missing attribution of answers (example here: `http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3555/can-we-do-something-about-sites-copying-content-from-super-user-redux`)
- `nofollow` in footer links to Stack Exchange sites (but regular links to the site otherwise)

Comment: At the moment, I'm seeing a parking page for it now.

Answer (score 0):

#### justlogged.com

- no attribution at all (at least not with JavaScript blocked)
- The last editor is misattributed as the asker of the question and the link is to the main page of justlogged.com
- Example: `www.justlogged.com/Question/3/2786/fb3f76858cb38e5b7fd113e0bc1c0721`

Comment: Site's parked right now.

Answer (score 0):

#### codinganswers.info

- does contain link to "original source" but no author attribution
- example question with **my own** content: `http://codinganswers.info/index.php/2010/11/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-v1-4-released/`

Answer (score 0):

#### www.texmach-intl.com

- absolutely no attribution anywhere
- example question with the same content as the above offender: `http://www.texmach-intl.com/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-2-released/`

Answer (score 0):

#### gamingqna.blogspot.com

- Content from accepted questions is actively being scraped off of [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) since July
- There is no attribution for neither questions nor answers
- The only link back to Stack Exchange is an obscure nofollow "more discussion" link

**Update June 2012**

- Appears to abid by attribution rules now - sidebar indicates content is from Gaming, author names for both question and answer appear and are linked, and a "more discussion" link goes back to original question

Answer (score 0):

#### 6-da.com

- Example (`http://it.6-da.com/show/6939570.aspx`) ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939570/glassfish-3-1-credential-error-in-eclipse))
- No names, links, or any attribution whatsoever. Contact link does not work.
- Requires one to subscribe to see the accepted answer! ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxQGy.png)) That reminds me of some other site...

Answer (score 0):

#### www.x2x1.com/

- Entire site?
- No link to original question or any reference to SO
- No author names
- Registration required to see the selected answer
- Example: `http://www.x2x1.com/show/6766034.aspx` `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766034/cancel-block-in-uiview-animatewithduration`
- Fortunately I have never seen it appear before SO on google search results, but it still is in violation.

Answer (score 0):

#### loopingrecursion.com

- *Probably* borderline. They DO show names and links on all pages, but the word 'stackoverflow' only appears on the home page: on other pages it's visible in an image, but I'm not sure if that counts

Answer (score 0):

#### asiantravelhotel.com

- Pure scraping, no references of any kind
- Example: `http://www.asiantravelhotel.com/c-begin-endreceive-how-do-i-read-large-data.html` (compare with [C# Begin/EndReceive - how do I read large data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582550/11410))
- Author names removed from questions and answers
- All the answers are rolled into one

Answer (score 0):

#### java.resourcezen.com

- Example: `http://java.resourcezen.com/how-to-copy-a-function-or-class-to-another-file-1`
- Links back, but no mention of StackOverflow, or the author's name
- Claims "Copyright © 2011 java.resourcezen.com All Rights Reserved" in the footer
- Probably other subdomains of resourcezen.com also exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**http://www.windows-azure.net**

My orginal question is:

[500 - Internal server error in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088550/500-internal-server-error-in-azure)

And copy/paste link is:

`http://www.windows-azure.net/500-internal-server-error-in-azure/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=500-internal-server-error-in-azure`

They are required to:

1 - link to the original question.

2 - list as the author and link to myuser profile page on SO.

Answer (score 0):

**cjavaphp.com**

- Does not attribute to SO (no mention found even in html source)
- No links back to profile for users
- Does not link to original question

Answer (score 0):

**www.windowslinuxosx.com**

Scrapes content from Super User (at least). The name and avatar of the author appears next to each post, but there is never any mention of Super User, any link back to posts of user pages, or any indication that the content is not original.

Example: `http://www.windowslinuxosx.com/q/answers-why-cant-old-pcs-view-modern-sites-628179.html` ← [Why can't old PCs view modern sites?](https://superuser.com/questions/628179/why-cant-old-pcs-view-modern-sites)

Answer (score 0):

"Acidmanic.Somee"

Sample scraped question from Mi Yodeya: `http://acidmanic.somee.com/surf/surf.aspx?dec=1&url=uh4QwdELmSFRtgfFwSQKwT47sSJByg0EsqVDt5V9vSQLwrpBwT4FvSVPmPAN0dsLxS7VmqBPmqBQmqVBsSpPwSfOy5RQvOR7wSIJs5ROsqj8u3==B6X!`

Copies the boilerplate including the CC-SA notice, but contains no links back to the site and no attribution in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

"TinyMoviez.org" + something in Arabic that I can't read.

Scrape of Mi Yodeya front page, no links back to SE or attribution: `http://s3.tinysub.org/sub/browse.php?u=Oi8vanVkYWlzbS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbQ%3D%3D&b=0`

Answer (score 0):

**digresource.com**

Examples:

1. `http://digresource.com/encouraging-users-to-be-more-specific-about-tool-or-server-versions-228135.html` is a copy of [Encouraging users to be more specific about tool or server versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87505/encouraging-users-to-be-more-specific-about-tool-or-server-versions) - **Meta**
2. `http://digresource.com/mac-mini-for-software-development-213747.html` is a copy of [mac mini for software development](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41729/mac-mini-for-software-development) - **Ask Differnt**
3. `http://digresource.com/why-are-tasks-in-microsoft-project-turned-red-86412.html` is a copy of [Why are tasks in Microsoft Project turned red?](https://superuser.com/questions/268206/why-are-tasks-in-microsoft-project-turned-red) - **Super User**
4. `http://digresource.com/how-to-restore-etcservices-205858.html` is a copy of [How to restore /etc/services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13555/how-to-restore-etc-services) - **Ask Ubuntu**