# Sort of copy of my question on a different site

Tags: discussion, support, attribution, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

I am not sure if this belongs here: [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/155556) but I just found a version of my question: [Why does $($) crash my page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9585840/561731) with it's answers, **but** with different names???

http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/7587/why-does-crash-my-page

Does that mean it is a legit site? Or just fancy scraping that they hid with name changes?

---

#### Sidebar:

I found the user who owns the site: https://stackoverflow.com/users/586227/ali-adravi

And here is his question on how to scrape the content from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3448821/561731

Comment: They copy a lot of questions/answers by changing the name of the posters. Also, they change the date (for example, your question was 2 months before on advancesharp).

Comment: It definitely belongs in [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846) I'd say; copying *and* obscuring the content to avoid detection.

Comment: Why wouldn't it belong on the linked question?  It's exactly an example of what's mentioned in the title (using SE content without *proper* attribution).

Comment: @jadarnel27 because it is more obscured. so they are saying (as Florian states) **we asked it first, you are copying us**

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: So they are being more devious about it, making them more guilty. Report them in the report thread with that information.

Comment: Meh.  Sounds like "He said, she said", which would ultimately be up to lawyers to determine who is telling the truth.

Comment: @jadarnel27 found the user who owns the site: http://stackoverflow.com/users/586227/ali-adravi

Comment: A question by Neal that I'm upvoting? What is this I don't even.