# Is this a hallucination?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it legal to copy Stack Overflow questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers)
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

I have been searching for some answers and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459630/how-to-write-settimeout-with-params-by-coffeescript). Then I still had some questions left and continued my search on Google and I came across [this post](http://www.advancesharp.com/Questions/5216/how-to-write-settimeout-with-params-by-coffeescript).

I do not understand here. Alright, that might be a repost to another website, but why is it dated a year later and written by totally different people? Where is the truth? Is that a hallucination? Or maybe StackOverflow is a hallucination, and you are not real people at all, and the real people are there at AdvanceSharp? Am I real then?

**UPDATE:**

You guys rock! :D Thanks for stabilizing me, I started getting into [derealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derealization) already.

Comment: that is hilarious - one of the answers references a comment that was not copied over :P  `Thanks @Joel`

Comment: `real people are there at AdvanceSharp?`i guess not(headbang).
may b all OP's are some random names taken

Comment: Maybe I'm getting old or something, but why does this "gimme teh codez" has 30 upvotes?

Comment: @UristMcBobby I guess that it is upvoted by many who step over the same problem. For me the resolution there does not work though :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> why is it dated a year later and written by totally different people? Where is the truth? Is that a hallucination? Or maybe StackOverflow is a hallucination, and you are not real people at all, and the real people are there at AdvanceSharp? Am I real then?

[image]

Seriously though, good catch. This looks like a scraper that violates the CC license.

[Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

Comment: Actually, [that site has already been reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136550/150097)

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/22893140.jpg

Comment: Multiple offenders... **`OFF WITH THEIR HEADS!`**

Answer (score 6):

From the Legal page of Advance Sharp -  http://www.advancesharp.com/Legal

> #### Copyright Notice
>
> Copyright © 2012 AdvanceSharp.com All rights
> reserved. Permission to use AdvanceSharp.com contents any where is
> granted but you will need to show the user images and main links,
> redirected to AdvanceSharp.com site, also you will need to show the
> content is taken from Advance Sahrp and it should be in bold, all the
> user images should be a link and will redirect to advancesharp.com web
> site.

how does that saying go?

`"Do unto others as you would have them do unto you".`

Just saying...

Comment: they even have spelling mistakes in their copyright notice... `Advance Sahrp`... what a sham...

Comment: What next?  Are they going to start scraping content from [meta]??  I'd like to see them try... **>:)**