# Is there something that can be done about DekTak.com inappropriately using Stack Exchange's name?

Tags: discussion, copyright-infringement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

While searching for answers to my question I came across http://www.www.dektak.com/

The [particular page](http://www.www.dektak.com/questions/10009985/server-sent-events-vs-ajax-polling-vs-websockets-for-notifications) is a scrape of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009985/server-sent-events-vs-ajax-polling-vs-websockets-for-notifications) but without the required attribution and it looks like this:

[image: picture of dektak stealing Stack Exchange content and name]

Is this OK with Stack Exchange? Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: See [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846)

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is a bit more than using content, they are using the network's name as well...

Comment: @YannisRizos: all the more blatant, should still be reported in that thread, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes it should (if it's not already, there are already 55 answers there), but I think it also merits its own Meta q (won't be closing as a dupe).

Comment: OK. I am adding it to that thread now.

Comment: "E-mail: info@example.com" - Is just one of the pieces of place-holder text on that page.

Comment: Abby is in charge of SE's ["list of people to threaten."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123875/131713) I've poked her about this post. I guess she's going to have a fun day.

Comment: Wait...you mean this isn't part of the StackExchange network?!! I JUST GAVE THEM MY GOOGLE LOGIN :-(

Comment: I like how they have the extra "www". You know, just to be sure.

Comment: @AnnaLear: [well, they're trying to save the web.](http://www.www.extra-www.org/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, that's a jerk move!

I've added it to the list of sites that we smack periodically with our ATTRIBUTION, YO! hammer. Hope they have good helmets.