# stackoverflow data is being copied by somebody on another website? Is it desirable? If no, how to prevent it?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

**Original Stackoverflow question:**
[This is original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600254/unable-to-understand-coding-logic-principle-convention-why-show-a-is-nee)

**Below is the link which has copied the original stackoverflow question:**

http://www.1771.in/haskell-unable-to-understand-coding-logic-principle-convention-why-show-a-is-needed-why-show-carquot-or-quotshow-stringquot-is-not-working.html

I don't know what to do? I just thought I should notify this incident to the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Put it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here

Comment: I have put this detail to Mystical's suggested place.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this and posting an answer on the question Mysticial suggested. We'll follow up on it.