# Good examples of sites, books, other using StackExchange content?

Tags: discussion, attribution, content-reuse

I've read a number of questions from people who want to attribute correctly, and from people reporting improperly or wholly unattributed uses; [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) seems to be a permathread on that.

Are there any good examples of sites, books, or other things using content from StackExchange not only in full compliance with the CC-BY-SA license offered, but also usefully (i.e. more creatively than mere republication)? I imagine there must be some good uses in textbooks, documentation, and training materials out there.