# Is this website infringing on StackExchange's copyright?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

Is this website infringing on StackExchange's copyrights?   Website directly takes content from StackExchange website, but I'm unsure whether it's affiliated in anyway to Stack Exchange at all.

http://www.tinyguru.com/

Comment: Seems like it. You might want to report it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already on the list of infringing sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148227/137004

Go vote it up.