# Create a software mechanism to report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules

Tags: feature-request, attribution, copycat-sites, screen-scraping, content-reuse

At the time of this post there are 87 answers to the meta question: [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846/61654). The sheer volume of answers makes it impossible to quickly discern if a site has already been reported.

As an example I've run into two such sites in the last week and in one instance was able to identify that the site had already been reported. In the other I was unable to do so and posted a link to the infringing site. A few minutes later I began receiving down votes for duplicative reporting. My initial reaction was "fine I'll just block these sites from my Google searches and stop reporting."

Since I do not want to just pick up my toys and go home I'd like to suggest that a better mechanism for reporting content reuse violations needs to be created. In addition to the infringing site the reporting system could keep track of:

- number times a site has been reported
- current status of the report: suspended, take down request etc.

A badge could even be awarded for reporting a site.

Regardless of features having well-intentioned users search through a list of nearly 90 answers to see if a site is already reported is untenable and creates a frustrating user experience for those trying to do the right thing. I would also venture that having a definitive and manageable list of infringing sites would be useful for those at Stack Exchange who are trying to manage take down requests due to the lack of content attribution.

Comment: This'd be nice, it could be a little form that lives in the Contact Us page

Comment: No software mechanism just yet but [big change in policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/152859) is taking place now.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this simple Userscript that checks existing answers for your link, alerting you if it is already present and partly filling out the answer form if not:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Report site
// @namespace   http://stackoverflow.com
// @include     http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/131846/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!b6vl_mZrTCYXgo&callback=?';

var reportbutton = $('<a id="report" href="#" title="report a ripoff">report site</a>')

reportbutton.on('click', function () {
    var link = window.prompt("Please enter the domain name of the site you wish to report");
    if(link){
        $.getJSON(url, {
            key: "awn3X8U)9erzSfhBhqSF4A(("
        }, function (data) {
            var check = data.items.some(function(v,i,a){
                return v.body.indexOf(link) !== -1;
            });
            if(check){
                alert('This site already appears to have been reported');
            }else{
                var conf = window.confirm; 
                window.confirm = function() { return true; }; 
                $("#show-editor-button input").click(); 
                window.confirm = conf;
                $('#wmd-input').val('**' + link +'**');
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#wmd-input').offset().top }, 'slow');
                //... Open answer textarea and fill in link
            }
        });
    }
});

$('#question .post-menu').append($('<span class="lsep">|</span>')).append(reportbutton);
```

There should be an extra "report site" item in the menu for the question you linked to.

Comment: Asad I genuinely appreciate the script, but do you truly believe it is a valid solution for the community at large?

Comment: @ahsteele Nope, just a workaround. Something better could obviously be implemented by the folks server side, but if you're having problems with finding whether a link has been posted before, this script should streamline the process.

Comment: Cool, agreed! :)