# My post is being supplanted by somebody else, but I did the investigation!

Tags: support, status-completed, answers, locked, attribution

I'm an active committer and PMC member of Apache MyFaces Project, known as (lu4242) Leonardo Uribe.

A year ago I posted this answer

[Difference between Mojarra and MyFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/mojarra-or-myfaces-jsf2-0-starter/6475710#6475710)

But it seems somebody else is claiming that the info was posted by he but in reality it was me who created the post, because I spent a long time to study it and resolve it.

Please revert the changes done over my post. My blog is this:

http://lu4242.blogspot.com/2012/05/understandingjsf-2-and-wicket.html

In this link you can see the first mail send over this feature in MyFaces dev list.

http://markmail.org/message/ctgf3cw4l4trh4ua?q=understanding+jsf+2+performance+comparison

Take a look at the PDF of the report:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/94007042/Performance-Comparison-Leonardo-Uribe-FINAL-Detailed

Comment: No need to shout; and only use the `spam` tag for actually spammers please.

Comment: The edits were made by a moderator, so there is something more going on here.

Comment: But is this the right place for this request? Could somebody help?

Comment: To be fair your answer was June 2011 and you are supposed to have copied it from a post with `/2012/02/` in the URL. Seems unlikely unless you have a time machine.

Comment: Just look on http://markmail.org/ with the words myfaces and lu4242 and you'll see I'm the real expert.

Comment: @lu4242: This is the right place, and I you may have a case, just trying to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: @MartinSmith Look at the revision history.  A substantial portion of that answer was added months after 02/2012.

Comment: @BilltheLizard But the edit changes the entirety of the post to a quote, indicating none of the content is original.  If only a few edits were accredited to this other blog post, the citation should indicate that.

Comment: I was the one who did the answer first and then I did an update. The first post was on this article: http://lu4242.blogspot.com/2011/06/10-reason-why-choose-myfaces-core-as.html

Comment: I created the answer, and then did a research and updated it

Comment: @BilltheLizard - The only edit before today was Revision 2 that is not particularly substantial.

Comment: My name is Leonardo Uribe, Apache MyFaces PMC member and the one who do the releases for this JSF implementation.

Comment: That blog is copying other SO content as well, for example  [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3623911) is copied to http://kumarnvm.blogspot.co.uk/search?updated-max=2012-1-15T22:02:00-07:00&max-results=7&start=3&by-date=false

Comment: @MartinSmith Ah, you're right. I misinterpreted the diff as meaning that everything *after* **UPDATE MAY 2012:** was added on that day.  I'll fix this, then get my eyes checked.

Answer (score 20):

Ok...my bad. It wasn't immediately obvious or clear that this was your original work. If that happens again please provide a link when flagging.

Can I recommend that you add a pre-amble at the start of your answer along the lines of:

> I wrote about this on my blog here: http://lu4242.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/understandingjsf-2-and-wicket.html

That will reduce the chances of this sort of thing happening again.

Again, sorry about that.

Comment: I must say that a few moments paying attention to the dates would have made it clear the post could never have been copied from that blog. The rest of that site is (to me) an obvious ad mill.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks guys for your help. I'll add the preamble.

Comment: But Kev, you didn't change the SO answer to state that it was pulled from lu4242's blog, you stated that it was pulled from kumarnvm's blog.  If you had cited lu4242's blog it wouldn't really be [much of] a problem.

Comment: @Servy - as I said, it wasn't clear at that time and when he/she flagged the answer that the work originally came from his blog. The answer was flagged as a copy-paste from (what we now know) the imposter site.

Comment: @Servy: Actually, he did provide his own links at the very bottom of his answer... where most readers wouldn't have looked.

Comment: I put the links on the top, so now I hope it will not be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Servy and in my defence what BoltClock just said.

Comment: @lu4242 thanks for doing that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - we handle a lot of flags each day (2.2k so far today)....mistakes happen, we're only human but the problem is now resolved which is the important thing.

Comment: @Kev: Of course! I understand how the error happened. It's just that your post has a hint of a suggestion the OP could have prevented the problem by linking to their own blog post.

Answer (score 15):

That blog is a Internet copy machine, mostly [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) (Bauke Scholtz) posts:

- http://kumarnvm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/jsf-2.html copies from [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0), or was excerpted from this [blog post by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.no/2010_09_01_archive.html).
- In http://kumarnvm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/using-mvc-design-pattern-with.html the blog owner claims to be BalusC *again*, copying [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications), or, more likely, straight from [his blog post](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2010/08/using-mvc-design-pattern-with.html).
- http://kumarnvm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/real-world-java-examples-of-gof-design.html copies [Examples of GoF Design Patterns in Java's core libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) (or rather, from [BalusC's blog](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2010/04/examples-of-gof-design-patterns.html)).

I have yet to find any post on that blog that is *not* copied from somewhere else.

The fact that this fooled a moderator is unfortunate; we'll sort this out and get your post fixed up again, I'm sure.

Seeing as this is a blog-post copying operation, and that it copied your own original post, you should file a [copyright infringement notice with Blogger](http://support.google.com/bin/request.py?&product=blogger&contact_type=lr_dmca).

Comment: Is it possible that the owner of the blog is in fact that person?

Comment: @Servy That has to be investigated, but I think that the right people to do so are the SE staff.

Comment: @Servy: No, BalusC is a Dutch guy living in the Dutch Antilles. His name is *not* Kumar.

Comment: @Servy: The third blog entry does say `This is a copy of my answer on stackoverflow`.

Comment: Damn, I wish I was moderator for the entire Internet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Because someone not named Kumar could never have a blog alias of "Kumar"...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: For all we know his parrot Chichiray may be some obscure translation of the name Kumar, so it may very well be his parrot running that blog. You know how parrots love copying humans!

Comment: @Servy: Bauke keeps a blog here instead: http://balusc.blogspot.no/

Comment: @BilltheLizard be ware what you wish for :) nightmares ahead :)

Comment: @David, even that line [is copied from BalusC's own blog](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2010/04/examples-of-gof-design-patterns.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would you repost it in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here including the links? Or I can do it if you wish.

Comment: @tohecz: I am more and more convinced that this site is copying individual *blog posts*, not from SO itself. That's a difficult edge-case, the blog authors themselves could certainly make a compelling DMCA case against that site via Blogspot though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Still, it steals contents of SO/SE, too, even when indirectly. (Which arises a question: If _I_ wanted to reblog _my_ answer from SE, do I have to follow the contribution rules, too?)

Comment: @tohecz: You license your text *to* SO under the [CC-wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). You are still the author and can do with it as you see fit. It *could* be that SE can make a case under that license, but the copies are not verbatim (but they *are* verbatim from those blog posts).

Answer (score 2):

If http://kumarnvm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/mojarra-or-myfaces.html is *not* your blog, that this is copying without following attribution rules. The correct place where to claim it is:

[Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

Once you publish your contents on SO, you do so under a cc-wiki licence which allows people to repost it wherever they want, as long as they attribute it properly.

Comment: While the OP may have a claim that some other blog "stole" his content, that's not what this meta post is about.  A moderator is claiming that the OP is the one who copied the content from that blog post, and cites that blog as the source.  The post should be edited to indicate that it is the original source of the content.

Comment: @Servy Yes, you are right. But this has to be done too, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it's not what this post is about, so it's not an answer to this question.  It's also most likely of much lower importance to the OP.  What's on some blog full of plagiarized content is not something too many people care about, but when the original author is accused of copying from someone when he never did, that's...likely frustrating.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. This guy Kumar is claiming that the answer comes from his blog, but its site is just a copy of many post of real people. The answer comes from my blog.