# Is the appcelerator Q&A website a replica of SO?

Tags: discussion

I visited http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/newest
and the general appearance seemed oddly familiar.

Have they copied the SO template or is it just my imagination?

Comment: ....so? Stack Overflow is not the only Q&A out there. As long as they don't use our actual content without the proper attribution, there is no problem. (And if that were the case, you can report it here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846)

Comment: As @Bart says, the design of Stack Exchange sites is not trade marked, probably many see its success and try to copy the design.

Comment: Heck, we even maintain a list of clones :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Ok, but the vote system, the tags, you-name-it disposition and the overall look. Come on ! I thought I was on stack exchange.

Comment: Ok, I did not know about this clone war list :)

Comment: To drag out a Dutch motto: *"It is better to steal something good than to invent something bad"*

Comment: Their website is so slow though !

Comment: LOL. They have separate tabs for "unanswered" and "unresponded". SO they faithfully copied the meaning of "unanswered", but don't seem to feel that it serves.