# Is Ask Overflow a part of the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was browsing the Internet to find answers for some questions I had about my activities today.

I came across the site `ASKOVERFLOW.COM` and was just wondering what it was about and whether it was a part of the Stack Exchange network of sites, like Stack Overflow, Server Fault, etc.

Comment: No, this site is not part of the SE network.

Comment: Please don't provide your Stack Exchange account details to this site. It is somewhat surprising that you need us to tell you this.

Comment: @Abu since no one has mentioned this specific site before, so I'm not sure about the downvote, but my guess is that the downvote is to say "Do not provide your account details".

Comment: I love the "site design / logo © 2013 askoverflow.com" footer at the bottom of that page. At the very least, Namco might have something to say about that.

Comment: A full list of the sites run by Stack Exchange can be found [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Refer to this when in doubt.

Comment: Also, regarding the downvote, keep in mind the [votes are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) on meta.  Please don't feel bad if you get one, it could mean anything and usually does not reflect the quality of the question.

Comment: Their tagging methods make me LOL so hard. If anything, that should be a clear sign it's not an SE site.

Comment: I like how you can [_Resistor_ with them](http://www.askoverflow.com/our-partners). Sounds exciting!

Comment: oh man does reporting something also gets down vote???

Comment: @Abu read my earlier comment about the downvotes on meta.  Don't worry about it, it doesn't mean much.

Comment: @Abu Complaining about downvotes rarely makes them go away. It's just meta rep.

Comment: @Asad ok then I'll let it go

Comment: Thank you.  I'll be using this as an example of what can happen when a Q&A site goes unmoderated.  http://www.askoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: Hah... Just see it's [User's list](http://www.askoverflow.com/users) :D

Comment: http://www.askoverflow.com/1104/how-do-i-program

Comment: They are using Unicornify too, Is nothing sacred?! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180277/askoverflow-com-has-stolen-your-unicorns-sad-but-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Stack Overflow clone built with [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/). You can notice it is not part of Stack Exchange because the footer doesn't list the other sites that are part of the Stack Exchange network.