# Askoverflow.com has stolen your unicorns... Sad, but true

Tags: discussion, unicorns, unicornify

I just stumbled onto this when looking at [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) and found http://askoverflow.com/ which seems to be a truly laughable rip off to say the least... But when I looked at their "[Top Users Page](http://askoverflow.com/users)" I was shocked and disturbed.

They've stolen your unicorns! Is nothing sacred!?

For those not familiar with the unicorn epidemic, see: [My God—it's full of unicorns!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)

Comment: Well, they're not really *ours*. Anyone is [free to use Unicornify](http://www.unicornify.appspot.com/).

Comment: @animuson Oh, I see. I thought the unicorns were purely a SO/Meta joke.

Comment: Looking at [Unicornify's Origin page](http://www.unicornify.appspot.com/origin) It seems that Meta was definitely credited with inspiring the whole thing...

Comment: It was created as a side project of a single person who happens to work as developer for Stack Exchange. Not sure if he worked here back then but it's not really relevant: anyone is indeed free to use it as @animuson said including those running pranks on "our" behalf. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know imitation is the most sincere form of flattery, but doesn't it feel wrong on some level? Does not some small part of you want to have a [William Wallace moment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zFAvzf0Mv0) and exclaim "You can take our Q&A format, but you'll never take our UNICORNS!"

Comment: Of course it feels wrong and frustrating but we can't do anything about it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know, just trying to stir up some cheap laughs, in lieu of an epic unicorn related battle.