# My question is shown on another site

Tags: support

I have found my exact question [on another website](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/05/using-java-to-launch-a-batch-file-which-runs-wmic/).

Is this something that normally happens, or should I file a complaint against that website?

Comment: [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

Comment: since they don't attribute SO correctly, file a complaint. See above.

Comment: It's already reported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177337/158667