# What to do with sites that are potentially ripping off Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

This site: [Wiki Jammer](http://wiki.jammer-store.com/) seems eerily familiar to our own Stack Exchange model, but a few things seem off.

- The wording of the [FAQ](http://wiki.jammer-store.com/faq/)
- The lack of the top bar colouring
- No 'Inbox' dropdown in the top left

...Actually, at this point I'm certain that they do not associate with us at all. Having said that, what do we, as a community, do when we come across sites like these?

- Do we Observe and Report (such as what I'm doing here)?
- Email the operators of the site?
- Contact Stack Exchange Directly?

Or do we simply just ignore it and move along?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: @hjpotter92 - That's nice, so I just add mine as another answer right?

Comment: What exactly makes them infringing? It's fairly obvious that they're not a Stack Exchange site (they're using [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), btw), so I'm not seeing an issue.

Comment: We wish them good luck

Comment: @balpha - sorry, I didn't mean to imply they were already infringing, I just wanted to find out how we address sites that **seem** like they infringe. I've removed the infringing bit.

Comment: Ha. Sort by most voted. One vote in 1.5yrs.

Comment: Also this entire site seems to be an advertisement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copying the general Q&A idea isn't something we usually have a problem with, as long as it's clear that a site is not an actual Stack Exchange site.

There are various [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) of our Q&A system around, so it's not surprising that some sites out there use them. In fact, various Stack Exchange 1.0 sites moved on to use some of these clones to continue their site after SE 1.0 wasn't offered anymore.

The bigger problem we have with people who copy the *content* without giving the proper attribution (see [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)), but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

<sub>Disclaimer: IANAL, and I'm probably not authorized to speak for the company on legal matters (but if I am, there shall be free beer for all).</sub>

Comment: Makes sense to me, thanks for clearing this up