# What is UserAnswer?

Tags: discussion, answers, stackexchange.com

Today, I came across this site which has an exact duplicate of an answer I posted some time ago on StackOverflow.com:

[Answer on UserAnswer.com](http://useranswer.com/answer/tfs-api-getlocalworkspaceinfo-always-returns-null/) (Note that a full citation of who answered the question and where they got it from is provided)

[Original StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959635/937623)

My questions would be:

- What is UserAnswer.com?
- What benefit would it provide? (As it does not contain the answer "score" and the only way to see the question it is associated with that I can see it to link back to StackOverflow)
- Are all answers republished or a subset?
- If not, why was my answer republished?
- If I decide for whatever reason to remove my answer from StackOverflow, will it live indefinitely on UserAnswers, even though I would prefer it to deleted everywhere if I decide to delete it on StackOverflow?

It does not seem like UserAnswers is affiliated with StackExchange in any way.

Comment: It is a 3rd party website that is trying to make a living of placing adverts on content it merely copied?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what it looks like. Doesn't seem legal.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here

Comment: @NickFreeman - They _do_ link back to [SO], though, so that doesn't infringe.

Comment: @NickFreeman: SE sites share content under the CC license, as long as they attribute (which they appear to do) they are within their rights as conveyed by the CC license.

Comment: From their [about](http://useranswer.com/about/) page: "UserAnswer.com is a friendly front-end where data from the Stack Exchange network of sites are aggregated and reformatted."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine.

Their about page actually explains the CC requirements and how they are meeting them:

[image: requirements met]