# Is this site supposed to be copying all of Stackexchanges info?

Tags: discussion, questions, copyright, copycat-sites

I hope this is the right place to post this.

If you go to the rather lengthy link below you'll see that it is one of my questions, with comments, and answers here on Scifi Stackexchange. I'm not sure if this is a copyright violation or if it's just a companion site. I wanted to bring it to everyone's attention just in case.

http://youranswers.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMM05qYVdacExuTjBZV05yWlhoamFHRnVaMlV1WTI5dEwzRjFaWE4wYVc5dWN5ODVNamcyTkM5M2FHRjBMWGRoY3kxMGFHVXRjR2hoYzJWeUxYTmxkSFJwYm1jdGQyaGxiaTF6YVhOcmJ5MTBiMjlyTFhSb1pTMTNZV3hzTFdSdmQyNHRkRzh0Wm1sdVpDMTBhR1V0WW1GcWIzSmhiaTFvYVE9PQ==

I hope I posted this in the right place and did the right thing. Thanks

Comment: See [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers). This was used before that: [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules)